# Include images in TOC?

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents

I've got a large document whose table of contents is being generated by the usual `\tableofcontents` command.  I'd really like to include a small image next to each line in the TOC.  How can I do that?

EDIT:
Answering the question in the comment below, I'm using Article, and I'd like a different image for each SubSection.

Comment: Which document class are you using? Will the image be the same for all entries in the ToC?

Comment: Related: [Adding a per-chapter image along with group of entries in ToC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31518/adding-a-per-chapter-image-along-with-group-of-entries-in-toc).

Answer (score 8):

Here's an example using the `tocstyle` package which is part of [`KOMA-script`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script). (You may replace `\rule` with `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package.) Graphics for the "section" ToC entries may be changed using `\setsectiongraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\sectiongraphics}{}

\newcommand*{\setsectiongraphics}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\sectiongraphics}{\protect #1}}%
}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\settocstylefeature{entryhook}{\rule{0.15cm}{0.15cm}\hspace{0.15cm}}% for all ToC levels
\settocstylefeature[1]{entryhook}
    {\sectiongraphics\hspace{0.3cm}\bfseries}% "[1]" for sections

\begin{document}

\setsectiongraphics{\rule{0.3cm}{0.3cm}}

\tableofcontents

\section{bla}

\setsectiongraphics{\rule{0.5cm}{0.5cm}}
\section{blubb}

\subsection{foo}

\subsubsection{bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can i add different picture for different chapter?

Comment: @manish See updated answer.

Comment: i need output like chapter name and below to that image name. Infront of it index (page number). Is this possible to implement it.