# Pretty Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I would like to know if it's possible to have a Table of Contents looking like the following, where the number of the page is the big number on the left.

[image: PrettytTOC]

The sections could look like in the following "uggly-font-formatted" example. If someone has a better idea for the sections and subsections...

[image: Section]

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31518/adding-a-per-chapter-image-along-with-group-of-entries-in-toc), it might help get you started

Comment: not necessarily related but few ideas here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19796/how-to-customize-the-table-of-contents-using-tikz

Answer (score 269, accepted):

Here's a solution with a redefinition of the `\chapter` command (as implemented in `book.cls`) using `\parbox`es and the `leftbar` environment from the `framed` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{127,0,0}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{169,121,69}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{{\color{myyellow}\vrule width 2pt depth 6pt} \hspace{10pt}}%
  \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}

\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addtocontents{toc}%
                                   {%
                                       {\protect\parbox{3.5em}{\hfill\Huge\color{myred}\bfseries\thepage}}%
                                         \protect\hspace*{.5em}
                                        \protect\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-4em\relax}{%
                                           \protect\begin{leftbar}
                                              {\scshape\small\chaptername~\thechapter}\\\sffamily#1%
                                           \protect\end{leftbar}}\par\noindent
                                    }%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Beginning to learn design with \LaTeX}
\chapter{Beginning to learn design with HTML}
\setcounter{page}{13}% just for the example
\chapter{Beginning to learn design with HTML and some other text to span more than one line in the ToC}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first `\parbox` will contain the page number; I just reserved space for two-digit numbers (`3.5em`); for three-digit numbers, the width of this box will have to be increased, and that of the third `\parbox` will have to be decreased in the same amount.

I've made some improvements and additions to my first solution. Now there will be no problems when loading `hyperref` (my previous solution was incompatible with `hyperref`); the modifications to the ToC emtries are now made with the help of the [titletoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package; I've also added redefinitions for the section and subsection entries.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{127,0,0}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{169,121,69}

\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\sffamily\contentsname}{}{}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}
  {\def\FrameCommand{\hspace{6em}%
    {\color{myyellow}\vrule width 2pt depth 6pt}\hspace{1em}}%
    \MakeFramed{\parshape 1 0cm \dimexpr\textwidth-6em\relax\FrameRestore}\vskip2pt%
  }
 {\endMakeFramed}

\titlecontents{chapter}
  [0em]{\vspace*{2\baselineskip}}
  {\parbox{4.5em}{%
    \hfill\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{myred}\thecontentspage}%
   \vspace*{-2.3\baselineskip}\leftbar\textsc{\small\chaptername~\thecontentslabel}\\\sffamily}
  {}{\endleftbar}
\titlecontents{section}
  [8.4em]
  {\sffamily\contentslabel{3em}}{}{}
  {\hspace{0.5em}\nobreak\itshape\color{myred}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}
  [8.4em]
  {\sffamily\contentslabel{3em}}{}{}  
  {\hspace{0.5em}\nobreak\itshape\color{myred}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Beginning to learn design with \LaTeX}
\section{This is a test section}
\subsection{Long subsection title and some other text to span more than one line}

\newpage\setcounter{page}{123}% just for the example

\chapter{Beginning to learn design with HTML and some other text to span more than one line in the ToC}
\section{This is a test section}
\subsection{Long subsection title and some other text to span more than one line}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **Harish Kumar** suggested in a comment, it will be nice to have some decorations for parts too. This new variation explores one possibility for these decorations:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% definition of some personal colors
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{127,0,0}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{169,121,69}

% command for the circle for the number of part entries
\newcommand\Circle[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
  \node[draw,circle, text width=18pt,line width=1pt] {#1};}

% patching of \tableofcontents to use sans serif font for the tile
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\sffamily\contentsname}{}{}
% patching of \@part to typeset the part number inside a framed box in its own line
% and to add color
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}}
  {\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{20pt}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\huge{\protect\color{myyellow}%
      \setlength\fboxrule{2pt}\protect\Circle{%
        \hfil\thepart\hfil%
      }%
    }\\[2ex]\color{myred}\sffamily#1}}{}{}

%\patchcmd{\@part}
%  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}}
%  {\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{20pt}}
%    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\huge{\protect\color{myyellow}%
%      \setlength\fboxrule{2pt}\protect\fbox{\protect\parbox[c][1em][c]{1.5em}{%
%        \hfil\thepart\hfil%
%      }}%
%    }\\[2ex]\color{myred}\sffamily#1}}{}{}
\makeatother

% this is the environment used to typeset the chapter entries in the ToC
% it is a modification of the leftbar environment of the framed package
\renewenvironment{leftbar}
  {\def\FrameCommand{\hspace{6em}%
    {\color{myyellow}\vrule width 2pt depth 6pt}\hspace{1em}}%
    \MakeFramed{\parshape 1 0cm \dimexpr\textwidth-6em\relax\FrameRestore}\vskip2pt%
  }
 {\endMakeFramed}

% using titletoc we redefine the ToC entries for parts, chapters, sections, and subsections
\titlecontents{part}
  [0em]{\centering}
  {\contentslabel}
  {}{}
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [0em]{\vspace*{2\baselineskip}}
  {\parbox{4.5em}{%
    \hfill\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{myred}\thecontentspage}%
   \vspace*{-2.3\baselineskip}\leftbar\textsc{\small\chaptername~\thecontentslabel}\\\sffamily}
  {}{\endleftbar}
\titlecontents{section}
  [8.4em]
  {\sffamily\contentslabel{3em}}{}{}
  {\hspace{0.5em}\nobreak\itshape\color{myred}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}
  [8.4em]
  {\sffamily\contentslabel{3em}}{}{}  
  {\hspace{0.5em}\nobreak\itshape\color{myred}\contentspage}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Designing with \LaTeX}

\chapter{Beginning to learn design with \LaTeX}
\section{This is a test section}
\subsection{Long subsection title and some other text to span more than one line}

\newpage\setcounter{page}{123}% just for the example

\part{Designing with HTML}

\chapter{Beginning to learn design with HTML and some other text to span more than one line in the ToC}
\section{This is a test section}
\subsection{Long subsection title and some other text to span more than one line}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, if `hyperref` is loaded, the part entry formatting will be lost (I'll have to think about this).

### Memoir document class

In some of the comments below there are suggestions to implement the style using the `memoir` document class. Below I present two variations.

#### First variation

This version works for numbered and unnumbered parts, chapters, sections and subsections, and cooperates with `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

% colors to be used
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{127,0,0}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{169,121,69}

% a modification of the leftbar environment defined by the framed package
% will be used to place a vertical colored bar separating the page number and the
% title in chapter entries
\renewenvironment{leftbar}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{\textcolor{myyellow}{\vrule width 2pt depth 6pt}\hspace*{15pt}}%
  \MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}

% a command to circle the part numbers
\newcommand\Circle[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
  \node[draw=myyellow,circle, text width=18pt,line width=1pt,align=center] {#1};}

% redefinition of the name of the ToC
\renewcommand\printtoctitle[1]{\HUGE\sffamily\bfseries#1}

\makeatletter
% redefinitions for part entries
\renewcommand\cftpartfont{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\hfill}
\renewcommand\partnumberline[1]{%
    \hbox to \textwidth{\hss\Circle{\textcolor{myyellow}{#1}}\hss}%
  \vskip3.5ex\par\hfill\color{myred}}
\renewcommand*\cftpartformatpnum[1]{\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftpartafterpnum{\vskip1ex}

% redefinitions for chapter entries
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\mbox{\small\@chapapp~#1}\par\noindent\Large}
\renewcommand\cftchapterfont{\sffamily}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0pt}{0em}
\renewcommand\cftchapterpagefont{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{myred}}

\newcommand*{\l@mychap}[3]{%
  \def\@chapapp{#3}
  \vskip1ex%
  \par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
  \parbox{4.5em}{%
    \hfill{\cftchapterpagefont#2}%
  }\hspace*{1.5em}%
  \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.5em-15pt\relax}{%
    \leftbar\cftchapterfont#1\hspace{1sp}\endleftbar%
  }%
  \end{minipage}\par%
}

\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
  \l@mychap{#1}{#2}{\chaptername}%
}

\renewcommand*{\l@appendix}[2]{%
  \l@mychap{#1}{#2}{\appendixname}%
}

% redefinitions for section entries
\renewcommand\cftsectionfont{\sffamily}
\renewcommand\cftsectionpagefont{\sffamily\itshape\color{myred}}
\renewcommand\cftsectionleader{\nobreak}
\renewcommand\cftsectiondotsep{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand\cftsectionafterpnum{\hspace*{\fill}}
\setlength\cftsectionnumwidth{12em}
\cftsetindents{section}{6em}{3em}
\renewcommand\cftsectionformatpnum[1]{%
  \hskip1em\hbox to \@pnumwidth{{\cftsectionpagefont #1\hfill}}}

% redefinitions for subsection entries
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionfont{\sffamily}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionpagefont{\sffamily\itshape\color{myred}}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionleader{\nobreak}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectiondotsep{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionafterpnum{\hspace*{\fill}}
\setlength\cftsubsectionnumwidth{12em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{9em}{3em}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionformatpnum[1]{%
  \hskip1em\hbox to \@pnumwidth{{\cftsubsectionpagefont #1\hfill}}}
\makeatother

\settocdepth{subsection}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}

\begin{document}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\textcolor{myred}{Test Unnumbered Part}}
\part*{Test Unnumbered Part}

\tableofcontents*

\part{Designing with \LaTeX}
\chapter{Beginning to learn design with \LaTeX}
\section{A test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Test unnumbered section}
\section*{Test unnumbered section}

\newpage\setcounter{page}{123}% just for the example

\part{Designing with HTML}
\chapter{Beginning to learn design with HTML and some other text to span more than one line} 
\section{Another test section}

\chapter*{Test Unnumbered Chapter}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Test Unnumbered Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Second variation

**projetmbc** has suggested in an edit to the original question a different formatting when including sections and subsections; this is a first attempt to produce this new layout.

Some remarks:

1. The `\StartMark` command must be placed before each \chapter command and `\EndMark` must be placed immediately after the last sectional unit of a chapter that will be included in the ToC:
2. Page breaks can occur for the sectional units associated to a chapter and will be dealt automatically.
3. The code needs at least three runs.

The code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% colors to be used
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{127,0,0}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{169,121,69}

% a command to circle the part numbers
\newcommand\Circle[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
  \node[draw=myyellow,circle, text width=18pt,line width=1pt,align=center] {#1};}

% redefinition of the name of the ToC
\renewcommand\printtoctitle[1]{\HUGE\sffamily\bfseries\color{myred}#1}

\makeatletter
% redefinitions for part entries
\renewcommand\cftpartfont{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand\partnumberline[1]{%
    \hbox to \textwidth{\hss\Circle{\textcolor{myyellow}{#1}}\hss}%
  \vskip3.5ex\color{myred}}

\renewcommand*{\l@part}[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \cftpartbreak
    \begingroup
      {\interlinepenalty\@M
       \leavevmode
       \settowidth{\@tempdima}{\cftpartfont\cftpartname}%
       \addtolength{\@tempdima}{\cftpartnumwidth}%
       \let\@cftbsnum \cftpartpresnum
       \let\@cftasnum \cftpartaftersnum
       \let\@cftasnumb \cftpartaftersnumb
       \advance\memRTLleftskip\@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\memRTLleftskip
       \centering{\cftpartfont#1}\par%
       }
      \nobreak
        \global\@nobreaktrue
        \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}

% redefinitions for chapter entries
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\mbox{\Large\@chapapp~#1}\par\noindent}
\renewcommand\cftchapterfont{\Large\sffamily}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0pt}{0pt}
\renewcommand\cftchapterpagefont{\HUGE\sffamily\bfseries\color{myred}}

\newcommand*{\l@mychap}[3]{%
  \def\@chapapp{#3}\vskip1ex%
  \par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
  \parbox{4.7em}{%
    \hfill{\cftchapterpagefont#2}%
  }\hspace*{1.5em}%
  \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.7em-15pt\relax}{%
    \cftchapterfont#1%
  }%
  \end{minipage}\par\vspace{2ex}%
}

\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
  \l@mychap{#1}{#2}{\chaptername}%
}

\renewcommand*{\l@appendix}[2]{%
  \l@mychap{#1}{#2}{\appendixname}%
}

% redefinitions for section entries
\renewcommand\cftsectionfont{\sffamily}
\renewcommand\cftsectionpagefont{\sffamily\itshape\color{myred}}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionleader}{\nobreak}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\cftsetindents{section}{7.5em}{3em}
\renewcommand\cftsectionformatpnum[1]{%
  \hskip1em\hbox to 4em{{\cftsectionpagefont #1\hfill}}}

% redefinitions for subsection entries
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionfont{\sffamily}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionpagefont{\sffamily\itshape\color{myred}}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionleader{\nobreak}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectiondotsep{\cftnodots}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{10.5em}{3em}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionformatpnum[1]{%
  \hskip1em\hbox to 4em{{\cftsubsectionpagefont #1\hfill}}}
\makeatother

\settocdepth{subsection}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}

% length to be used when drawing a line from the top of the text area
\newlength\Myhead
\setlength\Myhead{\dimexpr\headheight+\headsep+1in+\voffset+5ex\relax}

% length to be used when drawing a line to the bottom of the text area
\newlength\Myfoot
\setlength\Myfoot{\dimexpr\paperheight-\Myhead-\textheight-\footskip+5ex\relax}

% auxiliary counter to place labels
\newcounter{chapmark}

% Adds a mark and a label at the beginning of each chapter entry in the ToC and draws a line 
% from the start of the chapter to the bottom of the text area if the mark 
% for the chapter ending lies in a different page than the one from the end of the chapter.
% (the value of tjose pages is calculated using the label)
% Must be used right before each \chapter command
\newcommand\StartMark{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\label{st\thechapmark}%
    \protect\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,baseline]   
    \protect\node [anchor=base] (s\thechapmark) {};%
    \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{st\thechapmark}=\getpagerefnumber{en\thechapmark} \else
    \protect\draw[myyellow,line width=3pt] let \protect\p3= (s\thechapmark),%
      \protect\p4 = (current page.south) in %
      ($ (4em,\protect\y3) + (0,-1ex) $) -- ($ (4em,\protect\y4) + (0,\protect\the\Myfoot)$);\fi
    \protect\end{tikzpicture}\par}%
}

% Adds a mark and a label at the end of each chapter entry in the ToC and draws a line from 
% the top of the text area to the ending of the chapter if the mark 
% for the chapter ending lies in a different page than the one from the start of the chapter
% if both marks are in the same page, simple draws a line connecting the marks
% (the value of tjose pages is calculated using the label)
% Must be used right after the last sectional unit (that will go to the ToC) belonging to 
% a chapter
\newcommand\EndMark{
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\label{en\thechapmark}%
  \protect\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,baseline]   
  \protect\node [anchor=base] (e\thechapmark) {};
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{st\thechapmark}=\getpagerefnumber{en\thechapmark} 
  \protect\draw[myyellow,line width=3pt] let \protect\p1= (s\thechapmark), \protect\p2=(e\thechapmark) in ($ (4em,\protect\y1) + (0,-1ex) $) -- ($ (4em,\protect\y2) + (0,2ex) $);
  \else%
  \protect\draw[myyellow,line width=3pt] let \protect\p1= (e\thechapmark), \protect\p2=(current page.north) in ($(4em,\protect\y2) + (0,-\protect\the\Myhead)$) -- ($ (4em,\protect\y1) + (0,1.5ex) $);
\fi
\protect\end{tikzpicture}\par}\stepcounter{chapmark}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\part{Designing with \TeX\ and \LaTeX}

\StartMark
\chapter{Beginning to learn design with \TeX}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section }
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\subsection{A test subsection with a long title spanning more than one line in the table of contents}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\EndMark

\StartMark
\chapter{Beginning to learn design with \LaTeX}
\section{A test section with a long title spanning more than one line in the table of contents}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\subsection{Another test subsection}
\section{A test section}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Test unnumbered section}
\section*{Test unnumbered section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\EndMark

\newpage\setcounter{page}{123}% just for the example

\part{Designing with HTML}
\StartMark
\chapter{Beginning to learn design with HTML and some other text to span more than one line} 
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section with a long title spanning more than one line in the table of contents}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\EndMark

\StartMark
\chapter{Beginning to learn design with HTML and some other text to span more than one line} 
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection with a long title spanning more than one line in the table of contents}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\EndMark

\appendix
\StartMark
\chapter{Test Appendix}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section with a long title spanning more than one line in the table of contents}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\EndMark

\end{document}
```

The obtained ToC:

[image]
[image]
[image]

### Tufte

Here's a variation for the `tufte-book` document class:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcounter{chapmark}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\colorlet{mycolor}{BrickRed}

\titlecontents{chapter}%
  [0em]
  {\vspace{1.5\baselineskip}\begin{fullwidth}\LARGE\rmfamily\itshape}
  {\hspace*{0em}\thecontentslabel}
  {\hspace*{0em}\llap{%
    \parbox[b]{40pt}{%
      \fontsize{25}{30}\sffamily\bfseries\color{mycolor}%
      \hfill\thecontentspage%
      }\hspace{20pt}%
    }%
  }
  {\rmfamily\upshape\qquad}
  [\end{fullwidth}]

\titlecontents{section}
  [0em]
  {\vspace{0\baselineskip}\begin{fullwidth}\Large\rmfamily\itshape}
  {\hspace*{0em}\contentslabel{2em}}
  {\llap{\parbox[b]{40pt}{\hfill\thecontentspage}\hspace{20pt}}\hspace*{0em}}
  {\rmfamily\upshape\qquad}
  [\end{fullwidth}]

\titlecontents{subsection}
  [0em]
  {\vspace{-.15\baselineskip}\begin{fullwidth}\large\rmfamily\itshape}
  {\hspace*{0em}\contentslabel{4em}}
  {\llap{\parbox[b]{40pt}{\hfill\small\thecontentspage}\hspace{20pt}}\hspace*{0em}}
  {\rmfamily\upshape}
  [\end{fullwidth}] 

\newcommand\StartMark{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\label{st\thechapmark}%
\par\protect\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,baseline]   
  \protect\node [anchor=base] (s\thechapmark) {};%
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{st\thechapmark}=\getpagerefnumber{en\thechapmark}   
  \else
    \protect\draw[mycolor,line width=3pt] 
      let \protect\p3= (s\thechapmark),%
            \protect\p4 = (current page text area.south) in %
      ( $ (0em,\protect\y3) + (-20pt,-5ex) $ ) -- 
      ( $ (0em,\protect\y4) + (-20pt,-5pt) $ );
  \fi
\protect\end{tikzpicture}\par}%
}

\newcommand\EndMark{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\label{en\thechapmark}%
\par\protect\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,baseline]   
  \protect\node [anchor=base] (e\thechapmark) {};
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{st\thechapmark}=\getpagerefnumber{en\thechapmark} 
    \protect\draw[mycolor,line width=3pt] 
    let \protect\p1= (s\thechapmark), 
          \protect\p2=(e\thechapmark) in %
    ( $ (0em,\protect\y1) + (-20pt,-5ex) $ ) -- 
    ( $ (0em,\protect\y2) + (-20pt,2ex) $ );
  \else%
  \protect\draw[mycolor,line width=3pt] 
  let \protect\p1= (e\thechapmark), 
        \protect\p2=(current page text area.north) in 
  ( $ (0em,\protect\y2) + (-20pt,5pt) $ ) -- 
  ( $ (0em,\protect\y1) + (-20pt,2ex) $ );
  \fi
\protect\end{tikzpicture}\par}%
\stepcounter{chapmark}%
}

\setcounter{page}{123}% just for the example

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\StartMark
\chapter{Beginning to learn design with \LaTeX}
\section{This is a test section}
\section{This is a test section}
\section{This is a test section}
\section{This is a test section}
\section{This is a test section}
\EndMark

\StartMark
\chapter{Beginning to learn design with HTML}
\section{This is a test section}
\section{This is a test section}
\section{This is a test section}
\EndMark

\StartMark
\chapter{Beginning to learn design with \LaTeX\ again}
\section{This is a test section}
\section{This is a test section}
\section{This is a test section}
\section{This is a test section}
\section{This is a test section}
\section{This is a test section}
\section{This is a test section}
\section{This is a test section}
\section{This is a test section}
\EndMark

\StartMark
\chapter{Beginning to learn design with \LaTeX\ again}
\section{This is a test section}
\section{This is a test section}
\section{This is a test section}
\EndMark

\end{document}
```

Images of the resulting ToC:

[image]

Comment: With your minimal code you make it look easy. Looks great!

Comment: The alignment seems to be a little off on the right hand side. Otherwise, what a beautiful implementation!

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: I've improved the spacing; the titles will now extend to the right margin; changing the width of a `\parbox` this can be adjusted as required. Thanks for your kind words.

Comment: This is great. Don't know how I missed it in Nov. However, there is a slight problem in that adding `\section{Section A}` after Chapter 1, messes up the alignment of the subsequent chapter heading.

Comment: Pretty!. But adding `\part{Part name}` will not work somehow. (I do not know why).

Comment: @HarishKumar: what do you mean with `\part` will not work? Do you want parts entries to have some special decoration?

Comment: @PeterGrill: the problem you mentioned is now solved in the updated version.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, With chapters having such a beautiful decoration, parts will look very dull (IMHO). It will be nice to have some decorations to parts also.

Comment: @HarishKumar: new example added. Thank you for your comments and suggestions!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Very nice. I wish I were able to upvote `n` number of times.

Comment: When babel is loaded there seems to be issues: http://i.imgur.com/8FhzX.png Also it does not seem to work with the memoir class: http://i.imgur.com/fxbqI.png.

Comment: @bobicool: when I have the time I will take a look about using `memoir` (although I don't use that document class). For the problem with the `frenchb` option for `babel`, simply use `\shorthandoff{;}` before `\tableofcontents` to temporarily switch off the shorthand action of the character `;`. To switch back on the shorthand, you can use `\shorthandon{;}` after `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: One more vote to encourage you to have it work with memoir! ;-)

Comment: This solution causes error for starred version of \chapter. Eg `\chapter*{Preface}` prints `PackageWarningframedBoxa is void – discard it. -` instead of page number.

Comment: @Igor: yet another thing I'll have to check. Thanks for noticing it.

Comment: @bobicool: I've updated my answer providing an implementation for the chapter entries with the `memoir` document class.

Comment: @André: I've updated my answer providing an implementation for the chapter entries with the `memoir` document class.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks! It does seem to work but it generates some weird errors in my document (which loads many packages).  I will try to figure it out - I may have to come up with a separate question and my own MWE.

Comment: @André: OK; please let me know if you open a new question.

Comment: The errors I had (save one, caused by a conflict with mdframed) have all been eliminated by this change.  Thanks!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I should add (can't edit...) that the conflict with mdframed may be due to something else altogether.

Comment: I get no errors, but it seems to work partially: http://i.imgur.com/0zFsM.png

Comment: @bobicool: as I said in my code, subsection support was not yet available; now it is. I've also added a new experimental version with `memoir`, but is has some restrictions. The first `memoir` version is more versatile.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Would it be possible to have your previous memoir example support a table of content with appendices - where \appendix is used to switch between "Chapter" to "Appendix" and Numbering is done with A, B, C?...  right now the formatting of the toc is wrong in this case.

Comment: @André: I've updated the code. Please let me know if now appendices behave as expected.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Instead of having "Appendix A", it writes "Chapter A" in the toc.

Comment: @André: yes, sorry about that. See my updated answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I have posted another question to avoid derailing this discussion.

Comment: One proposition : it could be interested to combine such a beautifull toc with pretty fancy chapter headings like in this post : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23477/fancy-chapter-headings

Comment: @projetmbc: yes, it's a good idea. I will take a closer look at the designs proposed by Yiannis.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: hello, I have one suggestion for titles of subsubsections in the toc. It could simply look like : `First subsubsection | Secund subsubsection | Third subsubsection...`. What do you think about this ?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, can I ask how long it took you to come up with and implement this solution? (Say the first TOC. I suppose the next ones needed less time.)

Comment: @dochar: the first one actually took less time (10-15 min.) but is a very restrictive solution. The last one (using `memoir` and allowing page breaks) took longer (several hours).. and I am still working (whenever I find some free time) on improving the solutions ;-)

Comment: @projetmbc and Gonzalo: The answer has been automatically turned to CW. I changed it back to normal status, as it deserves it. It would be great if you would remove comments which are not needed any more. Perhaps flag obsolete comments of others too, so we could clean up a bit.

Comment: This was one analogical click bug...

Comment: @Stefan Kottwitz : I've deleted my unusefull remarks.

Comment: I'd kill for that `tufte-book` version compatible with `article` class.

Comment: If I only want to keep "Chapter 1", "Chapter 2" and so on above the "Chapter name". What should I put in my preamble? Have tried but it ain't work.

Comment: This is amazing! When trying to use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` in `memoir`, I get the following errors for both `\StartMark` and `\EndMark`: `Missing number, treated as zero \StartMark` and `Missing = inserted for \ifnum \StartMark`. Is this fixable?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It seems that none of these work with `frontmatter`. Are you willing to add this functionality, please?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina in the second variation of memoir class chapters with no number (chapter*{}) are not shown in the content. Is there a solution for it?

Answer (score 48):

Here is a solution using ConTeXt:

```
\define[3]\myTOC{% #1=chapter number, #2=chapter text, #3=page
    {\ssd #3\hskip.4em}
    \framed
        [
                    frame=off,
                leftframe=on,
            rulethickness=2pt,
               framecolor=darkgreen,
                  loffset=1em,
                    align=right,
                 location=bottom,
          foregroundstyle=sans,
        ]
    {{\rm\sc Chapter #1}\\#2}
}

\setuplist [chapter]
    [
        alternative=none,
        command=\myTOC,
    ]

\starttext

\placelist [chapter]

\setnumber[userpage]{10}
\startchapter [title=Beginning to learn design with ConTeXt]
\stopchapter

\startchapter [title=Beginning to learn design with HTML]
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result]

However, it is not optimal. It only defines the list style for the chapters. But since you didn't specify anything else, that's all I can do.

The command `\setuplist` defines the layout of the list in the first argument, here `chapter`. `alternative=none` tells the system that you don't want a predefined style, rather than to use the custom `command`, which defines the appearance. I set the page number to a two-digit value, otherwise it gets confusing, which number belongs to the page and which to the chapter count.

Comment: This is another great ConTeXt example! What's the use of `{\sc Chapter #1}` that seems to have lost the Small Caps?

Comment: Yes I saw it too and removed it from the code (and you posted the comment in the mean time ;) Does LM have sans small caps by the way?

Comment: Not that I can see; Read [An exploration of the Latin Modern fonts](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/robertson/robertson.pdf) (p 3).

Comment: @Werner According to the doc there are no sans small caps. I changed to roman ones (which in fact is ugly). The fine-tuning is is left for the OP.

Comment: Yes, @Gonzalo's answer reflects the same for LaTeX. Most likely the OP's images is from a PDF screen grab, with the original document constructed in some different publishing software.

Answer (score 26):

I have pached the solution proposed by Marco (1) to allow for starred version of the `\chapter` command and (2) to prevent wrong pagebreaks which sometimes occured (in Marco's solution) between the pagenumber and the chapter title. For the latter purpose I wrapped the  `\parbox` that contains `\thecontentspage` and the `leftbar` environment into the `minipage` environment.

```
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{127,0,0}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{169,121,69}

\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\sffamily\contentsname}{}{}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}
  {\def\FrameCommand{\hspace{6em}%
    {\color{myyellow}\vrule width 2pt depth 6pt}\hspace{1em}}%
    \MakeFramed{\parshape 1 0cm \dimexpr\textwidth-6em\relax\FrameRestore}\vskip2pt%
  }
 {\endMakeFramed}

\titlecontents{chapter}
  [0em]{\vspace*{\baselineskip}}
  {%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \parbox{4.5em}{\hfill\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{myred}\thecontentspage}%
   \vspace{-2.3\baselineskip}\leftbar{\sffamily\chaptername~\thecontentslabel}\\
   \sffamily
  }
  {%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \parbox{4.5em}{%
    \hfill\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{myred}\thecontentspage}%
   \vspace{-2.3\baselineskip}\leftbar\textsf{}\\\sffamily}
  {\endleftbar\end{minipage}\nopagebreak}[\vskip2pt\nopagebreak]
\titlecontents{section}
  [8.4em]
  {\sffamily\contentslabel{3em}}{}{}
  {\hspace{0.5em}\nobreak\itshape\color{myred}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}
  [8.4em]
  {\sffamily\contentslabel{3em}}{}{}
  {\hspace{0.5em}\nobreak\itshape\color{myred}\contentspage}
```

Comment: This *almost* works with `memoir` ... Any chance you might be able to fix it to work with it?

Comment: The page number of `subsubsection` is not changed in TOC, please add this feature

Answer (score 14):

Here is an [etoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) implementation. This is basically plagiarism of [Gonzalo Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35835/4686) which I have translated with some adaptations into `etoc` lingua.

It is fully compatible with hyperref, and needs the usual three runs to get the TOC correct (inclusive of page numbers).

*Caveat*: the fanciful formatting is **only** for the table of contents. The body `\part`'s, `\chapter`'s, `\section`'s are the standard ones. To customize them to look analogously to their TOC counterparts one may use `titlesec`.

**Update**:  the code uses in a better way the `\MakeFramed` from the [framed](http://ctan.org/pkg/framed) package; this seems to avoid strange page breaks which arose in the first version under some circumstances.

Also, the code compiles as is with the `memoir` class.(*) See however the code comments: particularly if one wants to allow lone chapters without sections (as would be the case in `memoir` with `\tableofcontents` which adds to the TOC a chapter-like entry for the TOC itself), a (commented-out) more sophisticated etoc chapter style must be made use of, for technical reasons which are explained therein.

(*) this needed `\etocsetlevel {appendix}{0}` which should arguably be made by default by `etoc` whenever it detects `memoir`.

The design has one user adjustable parameter `\tocmargin` which is a length, here set to have value `5.4em` (computed in the default sans font in default size), inside the `\etocsettocstyle` command call.

The code makes some efforts with penalties to avoid badly located page breaks.
This last edit has my best effort to control these pagebreaks. `framed.sty` makes it favorable to have a page break just at the start of any environment defined by its means, thus, it is difficult to avoid that  a Chapter gets separated from the just prior Part heading. I have added some small vertical glue between sections and subsections to encourage breaks there. Adjusting the `\tocmargin` value can be in some situation the fix to an annoying page break (I tested it in stress situations with short pages).

The current code give a result a bit more spread out than is apparent on these images, the pages are better filled in than here, but the breaks are at the same locations.

I have also added to the source code two `\localtableofcontents` for the two Parts.

[image: pretty toc 1]
[image: pretty toc 2]
[image: pretty toc 3]

The code:

```
\documentclass{book}
%\documentclass{memoir}
%
% debugging page breaks, but too short pageheight gives bad page breaks
% anyhow, despite my best efforts
%\usepackage[paperheight=12cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}

%% THE FOLLOWING IS TAKEN (STOLEN) VERBATIM 
%% FROM GONZALO MEDINA'S ANSWER

% definition of some personal colors
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{127,0,0}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{169,121,69}

% command for the circle for the number of part entries
\newcommand\Circle[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
  \node[draw,circle, text width=18pt,line width=1pt] {#1};}


%% (jfbu) This defines an adjustable length, which gives the position of the
%% section and subsection from the left document margin.
\newlength{\tocmargin}
% Its value is set in the \etocsettocstyle command below, after \sffamily


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% USE OF framed package

% modified (jfbu): it took me a while to settle on that way of using the
% framed package. Initially I had as in Gonzalo Medina's code
% a \parshape, but it applies only to one paragraph (this was from his
% code where the left bar applied only to the chapter entries of the
% toc, not the sections and subsections). Besides, I had some problems
% with disturbing page breaks in certain circumstances, and these
% problems seem to be gone now, I needed to do adjustment to \hsize from
% inside the chapter style. This is all gone now.
\newenvironment{tocleftbar}
  {\def\FrameCommand {\hspace{\dimexpr\tocmargin-4pt\relax}%
           {\color{myyellow}\vrule width 2pt depth 6pt}\hspace{2pt}%
           \hspace{-\tocmargin}}% 
    \MakeFramed {\leftskip\tocmargin\rightskip\tocmargin\FrameRestore}}
 {\endMakeFramed}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% THE PLAGIARISM CONTINUES, WITH SOME MORE MODIFICATIONS, 
%% AND  EMBEDDED INSIDE ETOC COMMANDS

\etocsetstyle{part}
   {\nobreak\etocskipfirstprefix }
   {\pagebreak[3]}% makes a page break before a Part favorable
   {% debugging:
    % \noindent\rule{\tocmargin}{1pt}\par
    %          \rule{\dimexpr2\tocmargin\relax}{1pt}\par
    \addvspace{1.5\baselineskip}%
    {\huge\centering
     \color{myyellow}\Circle{\hfil\etocnumber\hfil}\\*[2ex]%
     \color{myred}\etocname\par}}
   {}

% totalement instable: passer de 2ex à 2.5ex suffit à tout bouleverser!
% toutes choses égales par ailleurs.


\newif\ifintocleftbar

\etocsetstyle{chapter}
% don't break immediately after Part
   {\nobreak\etocskipfirstprefix }
% but allow break after section or subsection
   {\pagebreak[2]}
   {%\addvspace{\baselineskip}%
    % it seems that framed's code too easily allows a page break 
    % if some vertical glue is here, so let's use a \kern
    \kern\baselineskip
    \begin{tocleftbar}
      \intocleftbartrue
      \makebox[0pt][r]{\smash{\parbox{6em}%
                       {\null\hfill\Huge\bfseries\color{myred}\etocpage
                        \hspace*{8pt}}}}%
% use of \parbox, else framed.sty has a tendency to allow page breaks if
% multi-line name
      \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\hsize-2\tocmargin\relax}
      {\Large\textsc{\small \etoclink{Chapter~\etocthenumber}}%
%\\* does not do what I want. \par\nobreak does.
% But as we are now in \parbox, does not matter
      \par\etocname\rule[-\baselineskip]{0pt}{0pt}}%
      \par
      \normalsize\leftskip\dimexpr\leftskip+3em\relax
    }
   {}

% THIS IS A VARIANT ABLE TO COPE WITH CHAPTERS WITHOUT SECTIONS
% it is **complicated** because \etocname etc.. loose their meaning if one
% closes a group in the third ("prefix")  or fourth ("contents")
% arguments to \etocsetstyle. Thus, we have to save them before
% issueing \end{tocleftbar} to close the previous left bar environment.
% Although the code mentions \etocthelink, etc, it works also if
% hyperref is not loaded.
% \etocsetstyle{chapter}
%    {\nobreak\etocskipfirstprefix}% don't break immediately after Part
%    {\pagebreak[2]}% but allow break after section or subsection
%    {\global\let\ETOCthepage\etocthepage
%                    \global\let\ETOCthename\etocthename
%                    \global\let\ETOCthenumber\etocthenumber
%                    \global\let\ETOCthelink\etocthelink
%     \ifintocleftbar\end{tocleftbar}\fi%
%     \kern\baselineskip
%     \begin{tocleftbar}
%       \intocleftbartrue
%       \makebox[0pt][r]{\smash{\parbox{6em}%
%                        {\null\hfill\Huge\bfseries\color{myred}%
%                         \ETOCthelink{\ETOCthepage}%
%                         \hspace*{8pt}}}}%
%       \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\hsize-2\tocmargin\relax}
%       {\Large\textsc{\small \ETOCthelink{Chapter~\ETOCthenumber}}%
% %\\* does not do what I want. \par\nobreak does.
% % But as we are now in \parbox, does not matter
%       \par\ETOCthelink{\ETOCthename}\rule[-\baselineskip]{0pt}{0pt}}%
%       \par
%       \normalsize\leftskip\dimexpr\leftskip+3em\relax
%     }
%    {\ifintocleftbar\end{tocleftbar}\fi}


\etocsetstyle {section}
% avoid break after Chapter
  {\nopagebreak[3]\vspace{1pt}\etocskipfirstprefix}
% allow break after previous subsection or section
  {\vspace {1pt plus .2pt minus .2pt}}
  {\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[3em][l]{\etocnumber}}%
   \etocname
   \hspace{0.5em}\nobreak{\itshape\color{myred}\etocpage}\par }
  {\end{tocleftbar}}


% IMPORTANT: this is ALSO executed if the last thing
                   % before the next chapter is a subsection

\etocsetstyle {subsection}
% avoid break immediately after section
  {\nopagebreak[2]\vspace{1pt}\etocskipfirstprefix}
  {\vspace {1pt plus .2pt minus .2pt}}%
  % {\etocskipfirstprefix}
  % {\pagebreak[2]\etocskipfirstprefix}% allow break after previous subsection
  {\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[3em][l]{\etocnumber}}\etocname
   \hspace{0.5em}\nobreak{\itshape\color{myred}\etocpage}\par }
  {}


\etocsettocstyle{\sffamily\setlength{\tocmargin}{5.4em}%
          {\Huge\bfseries\color{myred}\contentsname\par}%
          \leftskip 0pt\parindent 0pt }{}

  % for memoir class: (does no harm otherwise) [Nota Bene: this should
  % perhaps be done automatically by etoc when it detects the memoir
  % class, for better compatibility]
\etocsetlevel {appendix}{0}

\begin{document}

% Use \tableofcontents* for memoir class, as the TOC itself should not
% appear as a Chapter in the TOC. The * works also with book/report+etoc
% but does nothing. 

% With memoir and without *, the TOC defines a  not-very aesthetic
% chapter entry in itself and one must un-comment the more complicated
% etoc style for chapter above.

% debugging
% \hrule

\tableofcontents*

\part{Designing with \TeX\ and \LaTeX}

\localtableofcontents

\chapter{Beginning to learn design with \TeX}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\subsection{A test subsection with a long title spanning more than one line in the table of contents}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection with a long title spanning more than one line in the table of contents}

% If this is un-commented the more sophisticated chapter style must be used.
%\chapter{A lone chapter without any sections}

\chapter{Beginning to learn design with \LaTeX}
\section{A test section with a long title spanning more than one line in the table of contents}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\subsection{Another test subsection}
\section{A test section}
\ifdefined\phantomsection\phantomsection\fi
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Test unnumbered section}
\section*{Test unnumbered section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}


\newpage\setcounter{page}{123}% just for the example

\part{Designing with HTML}

\localtableofcontents

\chapter{Beginning to learn design with HTML and some other text to span more than one line} 
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section with a long title spanning more than one line in the table of contents}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}



\chapter{Beginning to learn design with HTML and some other text to span more than one line} 
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection with a long title spanning more than one line in the table of contents}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}


\appendix

\chapter{Test Appendix}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section with a long title spanning more than one line in the table of contents}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Another test section}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for this other solution. Is there an advantage of using etoc ?

Comment: I don't see any advantage using `etoc` for this specific design, which was very convingly treated by [Gonzalo](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35835/4686) with `titletoc` or the `memoir` class, with or without the `leftbar` of `framed`. The `etoc` approach needs no extra mark-up (`\StartMark`, `\EndMark`) It uses the `leftbar` approach to have the long margin bars alongside sections and subsections. The updated code works also directly with the `memoir` class. Adding `\localtableofcontents` after a `\part` creates a local TOC with the same design for each part. Works with or without `hyperref`.

Comment: my usage of `framed.sty` is not satisfactory: if one takes the code above, uncomment the line with the lonely chapter, and the etoc chapter style necessary for it, with the `book` class, one gets an awful page break at the top of page 3. Reducing the `\tocmargin` from `5.4em` to `5em` fixes it. But this is hardly satisfactory. If some expert knowing `framed.sty` could explain why this incredible break, I would be curious to learn how to avoid it.

Comment: @jfbu As you seem to be the resident expert for `etoc` around this site, may I please get your attention for this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306933/change-images-in-custom-toc ?

Comment: @jfbu the code doesn't re-compile when we have two or more appendices.

Comment: I like that it's also compatible with the ```article``` class.