# Page number before Chapter title in the Table of Contents with memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I've seen in some novel that, in the table of contents, the page number is before the chapter title, for example:

```
3    Down the Rabbit Hole
7    The Pool of Tears
15   The Caucus Race and a Long Tale
```

How can I obtain the same using `memoir` class?

Comment: This post: [Formatting the title of the TOC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35903) is not related to memoir, but it might be a good starting point.

Comment: @mvarela: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I converted your answer to a comment because links to other answers do not qualify as answers themselves. Unfortunately you can't post comments to other peoples questions as long you don't have 50rep.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve the desired result in many ways. Below there's one such possibility; I assumed the sectional unit used was `\chapter`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% redefinition for the ToC title
\renewcommand\printtoctitle[1]{\HUGE\sffamily#1}

% redefinitions for chapter entries
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{}
\renewcommand\cftchapterfont{\sffamily}
\renewcommand\cftchapterpagefont{\huge\sffamily}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\l@mychap[3]{%
  \vskip2ex%
  \par\noindent
  \parbox{2.5em}{%
    \hfill{\cftchapterpagefont#2}%
  }\hspace*{3em}%
  \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-5.5em-15pt\relax}{%
    \cftchapterfont#1%
  }\par%
}

\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \l@mychap{#1}{#2}{\chaptername}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Down the Rabbit Hole}
\chapter{The Pool of Tears}
\chapter{The Caucus Race and a Long Tale}
\setcounter{page}{14}% just for the example

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code above will align the page numbers to the right; to get them aligned to the left, \l@mychap must be defined using something like

```
\newcommand\l@mychap[3]{%
  \vskip2ex%
  \par\noindent
  \parbox{4.5em}{%
    {\cftchapterpagefont#2}\hfill%
  }%
  \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.5em-15pt\relax}{%
    \cftchapterfont#1%
  }\par%
}
```

Using this redefinition (in the full example code above) instead of the initial one, one obtains

[image]

Comment: How is it possible to extend the left position of number to section pages too? thanx!

Comment: @user41063 : You can change the `l@chapter` like so : `\renewcommand*{\l@section}[2]{%
    \l@mytocentry{\Large#1}{#2}{\sectionname}%
}`
See the MWE of my question here which shows both Chapters and Sections : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547344/add-a-vertical-line-between-chapters-sections-and-page-number-in-toc