# Page number on the left with book class

Tags: table-of-contents

Using `book` class, is it possible (if I'm not wrong, not with `tocloft`) to put page numbers in the left side? It would be something as

```
  5       Introduction
 19     I Title first chapter
 54    II Title second chapter
107   III Title third chapter
```

I considered the following tread: [Page number before Chapter title in the Table of Contents with memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55607/page-number-before-chapter-title-in-the-table-of-contents-with-memoir), which however is only for `memoir` class, and the following one: [Formatting the title of the TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35903/formatting-the-title-of-the-toc), which however is a mixed question about index and particular format. I need "only" to produce the above format for a classical ToC.

=====================================================

Addendum
Here a working code, but only for `chapter`, not for `section`:

> ```
> \documentclass[a4paper]{book} \usepackage{fontspec}
> \usepackage{polyglossia} \setmainlanguage{english}
> \usepackage{titletoc} \contentsmargin{0pt}
> \titlecontents{chapter}[4pc]
> {\contentsmargin{0pt}\makebox[0pt][r]{\thecontentspage
> \quad\makebox[30pt][r]{\textsc{\romannumeral
> \thecontentslabel\quad}}}} {} {} {}
>
> \begin{document} \tableofcontents
>
> \chapter{Some text some text some text some text some text }
>
> \chapter{Some text some text some text some text some text }
>
> \chapter{Some text some text some text some text some text }
>
> \end{document}
> ```

=====================================================

ADDENDUM 2

Consider this code, whose realization I'm strongly interested in

> ```
> \documentclass[a4paper]{report} \usepackage{fontspec}
> \usepackage{polyglossia} \setmainlanguage{english}%{italian}
> %\PolyglossiaSetup{italian}{indentfirst=false}
>
> \usepackage{titlesec}
> \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\scshape\roman{chapter}}
> \titleformat{\chapter}[display]  
> {\normalfont\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}{\scshape\thechapter}{0pt}{}
> %%{\normalfont\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}{\chaptertitlename\space
> \thechapter}{11pt}{} \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
> \titleformat{\section}  
> {\normalfont\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}{\thesection}{0pt}{}
> \titleformat{\subsection}  
> {\normalfont\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont\itshape}{}{0pt}{}
> \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{3cm}
>
> \usepackage{titletoc} \contentsmargin{0pt}
> \titlecontents{chapter}[4pc]
> {\contentsmargin{0pt}\makebox[0pt][r]{\thecontentspage}
> \quad\makebox[30pt][r]{\textsc{\romannumeral
> \thecontentslabel.\quad}}}} {} {} {}
>
> \usepackage{titletoc} \contentsmargin{0pt}
> \titlecontents{section}[4pc]
> {\contentsmargin{0pt}\makebox[0pt][r]{\thecontentspage}
> \quad\makebox[30pt][r]{\textsc{\romannumeral
> \thecontentslabel.\quad}}}} {} {} {}
>
> \begin{document} \tableofcontents
>
> \chapter{Some title 1} Some text some text some text some text some
> text
>
> %\section{Some text title a} %Some text some text some text some text
> some text
>
> \chapter{Some title 2} Some text some text some text some text some
> text
>
> \chapter{Some title 3} Some text some text some text some text some
> text
>
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> There is a bad interference between titlesec and titletoc, but I'm not able to solve with a correct interaction between these two packages...

Comment: How do you plan on handling `\section`s in the ToC or other lower-level sectioning commands?

Comment: mmm good question... if I've got only chapters, there is no problem. Maybe sections would be inserted in ToC too. Again, if I work with article class, I had to produce the same result only for sections

Comment: It differs greatly whether you want to insert `\section`s into the ToC in `book`. If not (with something like `\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}`), then an alteration to `\l@chapter` (which is unique in a way) would suffice. So be specific.

Comment: Yes, usually, in `book` I insert sections too. So it would be useful to have both in ToC

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution that uses the [`titletoc`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titletoc) package; the important part of the code is

```
% chapter formatting in toc
\titlecontents{chapter}
[0.0cm]             % left margin
{}                  % above code
{%                  % numbered format
{\llap{\thecontentspage\hspace{.5cm}}\thecontentslabel~}%
}%
{}         % unnumbered format
{}         % filler-page-format, e.g dots
```

[image: screenshot]

Here's a complete MWE to play with.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

% chapter formatting in toc
\titlecontents{chapter}
[0.0cm]             % left margin
{}                  % above code
{%                  % numbered format
{\llap{\thecontentspage\hspace{.5cm}}\thecontentslabel~}%
}%
{}         % unnumbered format
{}         % filler-page-format, e.g dots

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{mychapter} 
\section{mysection}
\subsection{mysubsection}
\section{mysection}
\subsection{mysubsection}
\subsection{mysubsection}
\subsection{mysubsection}
\subsection{mysubsection}
\subsection{mysubsection}
\chapter{mychapter} 
\section{mysection}
\subsection{mysubsection}
\section{mysection}
\subsection{mysubsection}
\subsection{mysubsection}
\subsection{mysubsection}
\subsection{mysubsection}
\subsection{mysubsection}
\chapter{mychapter} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that nobody upvotes good answers today ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand cmhughes solution, for the page numbers are not on the left, as I asked...

Comment: @user41063 I don't understand- in my example the `3`, `5`, `7` are the page numbers, and are on the left, as you asked for

Comment: Oh yes, u're right! But it's like the code I posted above. The interesting thing would be to have sections too similar to chapters (on the contrary, I'm not interested in having subsection in ToC)

Comment: @user41063 so couldn't you simply copy the code I have posted for `chapter` and change it to `section`? to ditch the `subsection`, use `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}`