# Moving the page number in a table of contents to the left of the titles with tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, tocloft

I would like to move the page number from the right-hand side of a table of contents to the left, using `tocloft`. The page number should still be right-aligned.

The question has already been [answered here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166730/) for `titletoc`, but I would like to know if there is a way to achieve the same using `tocloft`. The question referred to suggests not, but I would like to check anyway.

I start with a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage[titles]{tocloft}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{\end{lrbox}}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section 1 title}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Section 2 title}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

That produces this:

[image: page numbers on right]

I am trying to move the page numbers to the other side:

[image: page numbers on left]

And in case you're wondering, this is what I'm actually trying to achieve (without the blue lines). I've done the rest of the formatting successfully using `tocloft`, which is why I would prefer to continue using that package rather than switching to `titletoc`.

[image: picture of final aim]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This update achieves right alignment, as explained in my added comment. The defect is that it will not work if `\thepage` is not the standard representation with digits. Also the placement of the page number is not so good in the case of multiline section titles.

> [image: page on left]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newcount\cnta
\cftsetpnumwidth{0pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont {\global\cnta}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum {%
  \makebox[0pt][l]%
     {\kern-\dimexpr\linewidth+2em\relax\makebox[1em][r]{\the\cnta}}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{13}
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[2]
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{315}
\section{A very very very very very veryvery very veryvery very veryvery very
  veryvery very very long section title} 
\end{document}
```

---

Without hacking `tocloft` internal redefinition of `\l@section` I don't think there is a way. Here is an attempt though. Defects

1. the section titles should not extend on multiple lines
2. the page numbers will be left aligned, not right aligned

> [image: page on left]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage[titles]{tocloft}

\cftsetpnumwidth{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftpnumalign}{l}
\toks0 \expandafter{\cftsecpagefont}
\edef\cftsecpagefont {\kern-\dimexpr\linewidth+2em\relax\the\toks0 }

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[2]
\section{A very very very very very veryvery very veryvery very veryvery very
  veryvery very very long section title} 
\end{document}
```

With package [etoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) one may obtain all of your layout.

Comment: I thought later about a hacky way, but only if `\thepage` prints out arabic numbers. The idea is to redefine `\cftsecpagefont` to be something like `\global\acount` with `\acount` a count registers. Then `\cftsecafterpnum` will do the page number placement: the advantage is that we can get it right aligned then, however it will still be difficult to position it higher up in case of multiline section name.

Comment: i've never done this with `tocloft`, only with plain tex (see the tugboat toc for the relevant example).  see whether it's possible to reorder the pieces that go into a toc line, setting the page number as the first element, followed by the rest, with the text hanging indented to the appropriate distance -- in other words, treating the whole thing as a hanging indented (ragged right) paragraph.

Comment: @barbarabeeton  using `etoc` and `LaTeX2e` all of this re-shuffling is easy to achieve. The page number is available as `\etocpage`,  the section number as `\etocnumber`, the section title as `\etocname`.

Comment: @jfbu I think it would be a nice addition to your answer if you could provide the actual code with `etoc`; it would show the power of the package. On a second thought, the question asks specifically for `tocloft`, so perhaps this is not the place to show the power of `etoc`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina yes, I think this might not be the place... besides, power comes at the prize of having to define the line styles... and once one starts one has to do it for part, section, subsection... this is why I tried to say here in the `tocloft` theme.

Comment: Thanks @jfbu, @barbara and @gonzalo. I did want to do this with `tocloft`, as I'd already done all my formatting with that (which took me ages) and I didn't fancy trying to re-do it all in `titletoc` with the chance that something else wouldn't be supported. However, @jfbu pointed out `etoc` (which I hadn't heard of) on another question of mine, and I've found that it's actually been fairly quick to customise my TOC as required. I'm almost there, but will come back and have another look at this question shortly. I've been posting my questions separately in order to try and keep things simple.