# How to change the Title of Bibliography Chapter into UPPERCASE (BIBLIOGRAPHY)?

Tags: chapters, titles, titletoc, bibliographystyle, mwe

I want to change the title of Bibliography Chapter into UPPERCASE like BIBLIOGRAPHY.
I have tried changing it using **\titleformat**, **\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}** and something like that but it's nothing.
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, twoside, 11pt]{report} % page layout of this document
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem} % a package for writing some chemistry equation
\usepackage{mathptmx} % a package for writing some math equation
\usepackage{graphicx} % a package for inputting some figure
\usepackage{lipsum} % a package for writing some random text
\usepackage[english]{babel} % a package for set the language of the document
\graphicspath{{images}} % graphic's path
\usepackage[
    outer=1.5cm,
    inner=2.5cm,
    top=1.5cm,
    bottom=1.5cm
]{geometry} % a package for customizing document's margin
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst} % a package for indenting first paragraph

% Table setting
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\usepackage[labelsep=colon]{caption} % table caption setting
\captionsetup[table]{name=\bfseries Table}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}} % table numbering setting

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow,multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{1em}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{1em}

% chapter title customization in TOC
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftbeforechapskip}{\baselineskip}      % allow spacing after each chapter/section entry
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{CONTENTS}
\addto\captionsenglish{\def\contentsname{CONTENTS}} %! Needed for babel? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35903/formatting-the-title-of-the-toc
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\large\bfseries} %!some command to make the heading huge and bold
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-0.25in}        % Title is 1in from top
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{0.5\baselineskip}% 1 double space after title
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries} % Can make it bold faced here; don't put a space in the {}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries}                         % Can make it bold faced here; don't put a space in the {}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftchapdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}             % Puts dots after chapter entries
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter\ }             %
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{}                    % Don't put a space in the {}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}%
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{}                      %
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{5.8em}

% figure caption setting
\captionsetup[figure]{name=\bfseries Figure}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}

% chapter's title setting
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\centering}{CHAPTER \thechapter}{0.5em}{#1}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{0pt}{2em}

% section title setting
\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{0}\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.5em}{#1}
\renewcommand \thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}} 
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{2em}{0.5em}
\titlespacing*{\subsection} {0pt}{2em}{0.5em}

 % equation numbering setting
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}

% Page Numbering Stuf
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

% Bibliography
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
    [0.5in]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.045]{image/.png}\\
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\input{chapter/chapter1}

\chapter{LITERATURE REVIEW}
\input{chapter/chapter2}

\chapter{METHODS}
\input{chapter/chapter3}

\chapter{RESEARCH SCHEDULE}
\input{chapter/chapter4}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{chapter/ref}


\end{document}
```

and that is the screenshot of Bibliography Chapter
[image]

**What is the package or command that should I use for changing it into BIBLIOGRAPHY? please help me.**

Thank you.

Comment: For the `report` document class, try `\renewcommand\bibname{BIBLIOGRAPHY}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, it's still the same, not change to UPPERCASE. Do you have other idea?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textsc{bibliography}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter:}
  {.5em}
  {\MakeUppercase}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

I made a fictional `ref.bib` document. I tried to put it together with your code, but your `MWE` is too long...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, when I add your MWE to mine (like the above), the Bibliography Title is disappear.  Do you have any other suggestion, please?