# New ideas for writing a thesis

Tags: bibliographies, packages, theorems, thesis

As many of us, I am willing to write a thesis full of maths, fancy environments and all that. Each time I investigate the internet for ideas I find myself ending on the same websites with boring thesis themes.

I would like to find new inspiring packages or templates that would enhance the usual environments you use for writing a thesis, e.g. theorems, titles, headings, bibliography, etc.

Any fresh/cool idea is welcome !

Comment: Use the [contour](http://www.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/contour.html) package for titles/headings.

Comment: I think `tufte-book` is a great document class. `:)`

Comment: Did you look in [Showcase of beautiful typography done in tex friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends)? There you will find some very nice formated thesis and some of them offer you their tex source.

Comment: @Ignasi : didn't know about that. Truly awesome !

Comment: Strange, I had neither problem to understand vanna's question, nor see its relation to Latex, i.e. I disagree to the ‘decession’ to close it.

Comment: I was surprised too. I understand that this question should rather be a community wiki though.

Comment: @vanna I'm one of the voters. `inspiring packages` and other listed things are completely subjective and also if there is a certain trick you want to do, you can ask them seperately. That's why I voted

Comment: @percusse same problem [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends) then. But I see your point, my listing is ambiguous. I would just like a listing of new fresh packages for writing a thesis. The rest is subjective. I think the answers I got so far are pretty nice so it is not a big deal.

Comment: @vanna you're right same discussion took place there too. So I'm contradicting myself apparently. However, that one is about overall finished products. What you are asking is general thesis ideas that are too broad. I'm currently about to finish mine and I know how frustrating it is to make it look good. But if you can narrow down to headers or any other particular detail, TeX.SE is known for coming up incredible answers. here is another great Q&A : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35825/pretty-table-of-contents

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suggestions:

1. Check carefully with the institution you are doing the thesis for.  They may have a mandatory or suggested style/format.  If you deviate for that you will usually discover you have to convert your style to the institution's style.
2. I would focus on content using a minimum of other packages.  I recommend that for the draft stages you use article or report (maybe book).
3. Here are some sites for alternate format if 1) allows this.

   a. http://www.latextemplates.com/ these templates are in Creative Commons.

   b. http://uk.tug.org/training/thesis/ these templates are all from European Universities and often very specific to that institution.
4. I recommend using https://tex.stackexchange.com/ and search for each of the items you wish to personalize.  These previously answered questions are a gold mine of some of the best ideas and techniques of the experts who frequent these pages.

Comment: Good answer! You can also search [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/search/) to find packages that are relevant to your task.

Comment: +1 especially for the latextemplates.com website. It looks interesting and promising.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the package [classicthesis](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis). If this is too classic beautiful for you, also its derivative, [arsclassica](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/arsclassica), has that classic, beautiful layout.

`classicthesis` is closely to Bringhurst’s ideas (see *The Elements of Typhografic Style*); no boldface or sans serif, but letterspaced versals and small caps, and italic in titles and heading. You may choose a nice maroon colour for the titles and headings.

`arsclassica` use boldface and sans serif in heading and caption, but still keeps a cool and evenly look.

Both packages have all the functionality you are asking for, including options for title page, parts, chapters, graphics, tables and bibliography.

If your university accepts ‘free’ layout of thesis, look no further.