# Generating table of content (TOC) only from file.toc

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I use `scrbook.cls`

How to generate TOC from .toc file information available with me.

using [Pretty Table of Contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35825/pretty-table-of-contents)
solution with `memoir` documentclass

*I want to generate TOC separately and i want to attach to main pdf file. (As i am not using memoir.cls)*

Comment: Sorry I can't understand your question. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I am not able to produce similar to  Pretty Table of Contents with KOMA script scrbook.cls.

Comment: @marco-daniel I got similar at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122373/how-to-remove-page-number-in-toc-for-part-entry-not-page-number-printed-in-toc/122374#comment273654_122374