# How to remove page number in TOC for Part entry (not page number printed in TOC pages)

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocstyle

I want to remove page number in TOC entry for Part (in this example 3 must be removed)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lmodern}% for sans-serif plus bold plus italic

\renewcommand\partname{Module}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\usetocstyle{nopagecolumn}
\settocstylefeature{pagenumberhook}{\itshape}

\settocfeature{pagenumberhook}{~}
\renewcommand*{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{part}{}{\protect\parbox{\textwidth}{\protect\centering#2}}% original #1 in second argument
}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First Module}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Answer update from **lockstep** answer

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}% for sans-serif plus bold plus italic

\renewcommand\partname{Module}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\usetocstyle{nopagecolumn}
\settocstylefeature{pagenumberhook}{\itshape~}
\makeatletter
\settocstylefeature[-1]{pagenumberhook}{\@gobble}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{part}{}{\protect\parbox{\textwidth}{\protect\centering Module #1 ~--~ #2}}% original #1 in second argument
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First Module}

\blinddocument

\part{Second Module}

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please consider to accept marco Daniel's answer instead of my one.

Comment: @lockstep "Module" is missing in front of the part number i need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your requirements can be achieve by `tocstyle` without any redefinitions of internal commands with the the following two lines:

```
\settocstylefeature[-1]{entryhook}{\hfil}%centering part entry
\settocstylefeature[-1]{pagenumberbox}{\csname @gobble\endcsname}%no page numbers for part
```

Here the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lmodern}% for sans-serif plus bold plus italic

\renewcommand\partname{Module}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\usetocstyle{nopagecolumn}
\settocstylefeature[-1]{entryhook}{\hfil}%centering part entry
\settocstylefeature[-1]{pagenumberbox}{\csname @gobble\endcsname}%no page numbers for part

\settocstylefeature{pagenumberhook}{\itshape~}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First Module}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

---

Some modifications related to the comments of the OP.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}% for sans-serif plus bold plus italic

\renewcommand\partname{Module}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\usetocstyle{nopagecolumn}
\settocstylefeature[-1]{entryhook}{\hfil\partname\space}%centering part entry
\settocstylefeature[-1]{pagenumberbox}{\csname @gobble\endcsname}%no page numbers for part
\settocstylefeature[0]{leaders}{\hfill}%
\settocstylefeature{pagenumberhook}{\itshape~}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First Module}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, is it possible to make nopagecolumn does not change the chapter page number. Only for chapters page number must be printed at the right.

Comment: "Module" is missing in front of the part number.

Comment: @sandu: I implemented all.

Answer (score 3):

`\settocstylefeature[-1]{pagenumberhook}{\@gobble}` does the trick. Note that the last of multiple `\settocstylefeature` instructions for the same level overrides the others.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lmodern}% for sans-serif plus bold plus italic

\renewcommand\partname{Module}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\usetocstyle{nopagecolumn}
\settocstylefeature{pagenumberhook}{\itshape~}
\makeatletter
\settocstylefeature[-1]{pagenumberhook}{\@gobble}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{part}{}{\protect\parbox{\textwidth}{\protect\centering#2}}% original #1 in second argument
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First Module}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can we add Module - I in the part title. Sample part title: "Module - I First Module"

Comment: \renewcommand*{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{part}{}{\protect\parbox{\textwidth}{\protect\centering Module #1 ~--~ #2}} Gives what i want.

Comment: @sandu Nice -- I'm not familiar with `\addparttocentry`.