# Center chapter name in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, chapters

I am adding chapter name for a set of sections with the following code:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Chapter I}
```

However, Chapter I is left-sided. What I want is something like:

```
        Chapter I

1. Introduction...

2. Related work

3. ...

        Chapter II

6. Section bla bla
```

where Chapter I and Chapter II are centered.

How can I enforce that without touching my document class?

I found an ugly, yet effective solution:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\centering{}Chapter I}
```

It is not really chapter, but part with the name Chapter I. I know that this is ugly solution. When I used *section* or *chapter*, it was kind of merging with the next line or being centered in the first half of the widthline.

Comment: Please always post a complete small document not just a fragment. But how come in `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Chapter I}`  you are adding the TOC entry by hand rather than it being added automatically by the `\chapter` command, and how come you are adding it at the `section` rather than `chapter` level? It is hard to answer (or test the answer) without more context.

Comment: this question shows centered elements in toc: [How to remove page number in TOC for Part entry (not page number printed in TOC pages)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122373/579)

Comment: Do you have an actual chapter page, or do you just push content to the ToC? What `\documentclass` are you using? Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that we can use to gauge your requirements...

Comment: @Werner I am using INFORMS3 for OPRE document class. I just found out a way to center it by doing \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\centering{}Chapter I}%

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the journal class [`informs3.cls`](https://www.informs.org/Find-Research-Publications/INFORMS-Journals/Author-Portal/LaTeX-Style-Files), it does not provide `\chapter`s. You can modify `\chapter` to insert a "chapter-like entry in the ToC" or merely write what you want to the ToC. I've done the latter since it's faster/easier:

[image]

```
\documentclass{informs3}% https://www.informs.org/Find-Research-Publications/INFORMS-Journals/Author-Portal/LaTeX-Style-Files
\newcommand{\chapter}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{{\protect\centering\itshape #1\par}}
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Methodology}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Related work}
\section{More stuff}
\chapter{Residual}
\section{Final remarks}
\section{Conclusions}
\end{document}
```

You may want to add similar titles/headings in your main document. However, that's left to you.