# Modifying the look of table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tikz-styles

How to modify the table of contents to appear similar to this.Alignments are temporary but it should be similar.How do I do it?[image]

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35825/pretty-table-of-contents

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,162,232}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\renewcommand\contentsname{\textcolor{myblue}{\itshape\large Whats inside...}}\makeatletter

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    {\centering\contentsname\par\bigskip}
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip\hfill
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[
         fill=myblue,
         text width=\dimexpr.65\linewidth-8pt\relax,
         rounded corners=3pt,
         text height=3ex,
         text depth=1.8ex
       ] (secen)
      {\parbox{2.6em}{\mbox{}}%
           \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-8pt-2.6em\relax}{%
             \raggedright\normalfont\itshape\textcolor{white}{#1}}%
      };
      \node[circle,fill=white,inner sep=5pt] at ([xshift=18pt]secen.west) {};
      \end{tikzpicture}\hfill\null\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A title for the first section}
\section{A title for the second section}
\section{A title for the third section; it will span several lines}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using packages such as `titlesec` and/or `titletoc`, the number of lines of code can be reduced.