# Memoir: Custom Table of Contents with "veelo" Chapter Style

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

For my master's thesis I would like a ToC of the following format:

page |  CHAPTER 1 Introduction

page |  CHAPTER 2 Theory and Principles

page |  CHAPTER 3 Methodology

etc... (the "|"s represent a vertical rule separating the page numbers)

However, I have absolutely no idea how I would proceed to modify the ToC. I have been reading the Memoir manual, but I am having trouble understanding the various codes needed - and frankly, my LaTeX understanding is not good enough for me to do something like this myself. I would also like the "Contents heading" to be unaffected, since I would like to use the "veelo" chapter style (for the thumb induces). The formatting should apply to chapters and sections.

I would appreciate any pointers and help, and tex.stackexchange will definitely be mentioned in my acknowledgements as I would not be able to do anything without all the information on here!

Working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright]{memoir}

\author{Myself and I}
\title{Awesome Master's Thesis Title}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\chapterstyle{veelo}
\pagestyle{Ruled}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Theory and Principles}
\lipsum[1]

    \section{ICP-MS}
    \lipsum[2]

    \section{ICP-OES}
    \lipsum[3]

    \section{X-Ray Diffraction}
    \lipsum[4]

    \section{Scanning Electron Microscopy}
    \lipsum[5]

\chapter{Methodology}


\end{document}
```

Regards,
Anders

Comment: Have you tried to `tocloft` package?

Comment: So basically you just want the page number for chapter entries to be to the left of the entries? (I just want to be sure I understand your question correctly). Which should be the alignment for the page number with respec to to other entries? Should it go in the margin, for example?

Comment: I have read the tocloft documentation, but I was not able to make much of it; I am all "try and fail" on LaTeX, and lack any introductory and basic knowledge. (Maybe I should just work my way through the various companions).

@GonzaloMedina Yes, you are correct. Basically i want the column of page numbers on the left side of the entries.

Seeing as how the Contents heading will be on the right hand side, I do not want the ToC too far left, which might lead to some odd white space in the middle. Page numbers by the margin, not in the margin.

Comment: And is this just for chapter entries or for all entries?

Comment: All entries, I would think. I am sorry for not clarifying that!

Comment: [Similar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35825/pretty-table-of-contents/35835#35835).

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be very helpful, especially since you want the solution to be compatible with your existing class and chapter/section layout. Providing this code makes it a lot easier for people to help you since they are not required to start for scratch.

Comment: MWE added. Or at least compilable code - not sure if it is minimal.