# My personal TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, parts

I have read about this:
[Pretty table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35825/pretty-table-of-contents)

Can someone tell me how to do that circle for my \part?
I tried to copy some code but obviously did not work.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,calc,blindtext}
\usepackage{xwatermark,wallpaper,grffile}
\usepackage{bm,graphicx,empheq,etoolbox}
\usepackage{units,cancel,mathtools,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage{varwidth,verbatim,setspace,lmodern}
\usepackage{anyfontsize,rotating,framed,titletoc}
\usepackage{amsmath,tocloft, amssymb,fancyhdr,color,contour}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,multirow,marginnote}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,theorems,skins,breakable
,theorems,many,raster}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, anchorcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=black,pdfstartpage=5}
\usepackage{listings, float, wasysym}
\floatstyle{boxed}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,decorations.text}



\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{\cftsecnumwidth}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\sffamily\contentsname}{}{}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{6ex}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0ex}

%---this doesn't work!--------------
\newcommand\mycircle[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node[draw=yellow,circle, text width=18pt,line width=1pt,align=center] {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}}
  {\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{20pt}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\huge{\protect\color{yellow}%
      \setlength\fboxrule{2pt}\protect\mycircle{%
        \hfil\thepart\hfil%
      }%
    }\\[2ex]\color{red}\sffamily#1}}{}{}
%----------------------------



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First Part}

\chapter{My first}
    \section{section 1}
    \subsection{stuff1}
        \subsubsection{substuff1}
    \subsection{stuff2}
    \subsection{stuff3}

\chapter{My second}
\section{section 2}

-----------

\part{Second Part}
\chapter{My third}
\section{section 3}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This preamble is a real mess. Did you notice that you load some packages more than once? Most of the packages aren't needed for the ToC related issue at all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hyperref` redefines `\@part` etc. considerably, so `\patchcmd{...}` after using `hyperref` is too late. The patches has to be done before `hyperref` is loaded.

Writing something fragile like `tikzpicture` command to the `.aux` and `.toc` file is difficult, it's better to robustify the `\mycircle` command then!

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xwatermark}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\usepackage{bm,graphicx,empheq}
\usepackage{units,cancel,mathtools,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage{varwidth,verbatim,setspace,lmodern}
\usepackage{anyfontsize,rotating,framed,titletoc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,contour}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,multirow,marginnote}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{float}



\makeatletter
\newcommand\mycircle[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \node[draw=blue,circle, text width=18pt,line width=1pt,align=center] {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\robustify{\mycircle}
\xpatchcmd{\@part}{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
  }{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\huge\texorpdfstring{\hfil\protect\color{blue}%
        \mycircle{%
        \thepart}\hfil%%
      \\[2ex]\color{red}\sffamily#1}{#1}}%
  }{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failed}}


%----------------------------

\makeatother


\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, anchorcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=black,pdfstartpage=5}
%\floatstyle{boxed}

\setlength\parindent{0em}
%\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,decorations.text}



\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{\cftsecnumwidth}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\sffamily\contentsname}{}{}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{6ex}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0ex}

%---this doesn't work!--------------


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First Part}

\chapter{My first}
    \section{section 1}
    \subsection{stuff1}
        \subsubsection{substuff1}
    \subsection{stuff2}
    \subsection{stuff3}

\chapter{My second}
\section{section 2}

-----------

\part{Second Part}
\chapter{My third}
\section{section 3}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Francesco: You're welcome. It's in fact not easy without some knowledge about LaTeX.

Comment: be careful to pagebreak.

Comment: @touhami: Yes, that might be a bottleneck ;-)