# frontmatter command causing error when used with custom ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, titletoc, front-matter

I've been playing with [this pretty ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35835/121944), with the goal of simplifying it for my needs. I have successfully done that, but when I try to implement it into my bigger file, `\frontmatter` seems to cause an error, yet the code runs error-free without `\frontmatter`.

The error produced,  is:

`! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\ttl@tocentry ... #5{#7}\strut \kern \z@ }\fi {#6}
\ifcase #1\relax \ifttl@fr...
l.1 \contentsline {chapter}{A chapter}{i}`

There is no missing `}` in the code, so there is some deeper issue. I've been researching this error but don't understand how to fix it.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[compact,pagestyles,clearempty]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% % % pretty ToC modified from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35825/pretty-table-of-contents
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\rmfamily\contentsname}{}{}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}
  {\def\FrameCommand{\hspace{26.7em}%
    {\vrule width 2pt depth 3pt}\hspace{1em}}%
    \MakeFramed{\parshape 1 0cm \dimexpr\textwidth-6em\relax\FrameRestore}\vskip2pt%
  }
 {\endMakeFramed}

\titlecontents{chapter}
  [0em]{\vspace*{0.3\baselineskip}}
  {\parbox{14.8em}{%
    \hfill\huge\rmfamily\bfseries\thecontentspage}%
   \vspace*{-2.4\baselineskip}\leftbar\textsc{\normalsize\chaptername~\thecontentslabel}\\\normalsize\rmfamily}
  {}{\endleftbar}
% % %

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
%\frontmatter   %untoggle to see error(s)
\chapter{A chapter}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Another chapter}
\chapter{Another chapter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With frontmatter the chapter is unnumbered. The argument of `titlecontents` is empty and so you end with an lonely `\endleftbar` which hasn't a opening `\leftbar`:

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[compact,pagestyles,clearempty]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% % % pretty ToC modified from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35825/pretty-table-of-contents
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\rmfamily\contentsname}{}{}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}
  {\def\FrameCommand{\hspace{26.7em}%
    {\vrule width 2pt depth 3pt}\hspace{1em}}%
    \MakeFramed{\parshape 1 0cm \dimexpr\textwidth-6em\relax\FrameRestore}\vskip2pt%
  }
 {\endMakeFramed}

\titlecontents{chapter}
  [0em]{\vspace*{0.3\baselineskip}}
  {\parbox{14.8em}{%
    \hfill\huge\rmfamily\bfseries\thecontentspage}%
   \vspace*{-2.4\baselineskip}\leftbar\textsc{\normalsize\chaptername~\thecontentslabel}\\\normalsize\rmfamily}
  {\parbox{14.8em}{% <----- new
    \hfill\huge\rmfamily\bfseries\thecontentspage}% <---new
   \vspace* {-2.4\baselineskip}\leftbar\textsc{\normalsize\chaptername~\thecontentslabel}\\\normalsize\rmfamily}
  {\endleftbar}
% % %

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\frontmatter   %untoggle to see error(s)
\chapter{A chapter}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Another chapter}
\chapter{Another chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see. I will want a lowercase roman numeral to the left of that bar for the `frontmatter` content.

Comment: Would you prefer I start a new question for the numbering issue?

Comment: Where is the problem? Copy the code from the numbered case and adapt it if needed.

Comment: I must not be following, because I've played around with your code and still can't make it work for`frontmatter` numbering.

Comment: I edited the answer and copied the code.

Comment: Great. That's not even close to what I was doing :)