# Part Number separated of Part Name in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I've created this simplified TOC based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35835/121944) amazing post.

**MWE:**

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[
    paperwidth=8in,
    paperheight=10in,
    inner=0.5in,
    outer=0.5in,
    bindingoffset=0.25in,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=1.25in,
    twoside,
    %showframe
    ]{geometry} 


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35835/121944, basis of this ToC design
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[compact,pagestyles,clearempty]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% % %
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\rmfamily\contentsname}{}{}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}
  {\def\FrameCommand{\hspace{26.75em}%
    {\vrule width 2pt depth 3pt}\hspace{1em}}%
    \MakeFramed{\parshape 1 0cm \dimexpr\textwidth-6em\relax\FrameRestore}\vskip2pt%
  }
 {\endMakeFramed}

\titlecontents{part}
  [0em]{\vspace*{0.3\baselineskip}}
  {\parbox{14.8em}{% mainmatter
    \hfill\huge\rmfamily\bfseries}%
   \vspace*{-2.4\baselineskip}\leftbar\MakeUppercase{\normalsize{Part~}\thecontentslabel}\\\normalsize\rmfamily}
  {\parbox{14.5em}{% frontmatter
    \hfill\Large\rmfamily\bfseries}%
   \vspace*{-1.95\baselineskip}\leftbar\MakeUppercase{\normalsize{Part~}\thecontentslabel}\\\normalsize\rmfamily}
  {\endleftbar}
% % %

\titlecontents{chapter}
  [0em]{\vspace*{0.3\baselineskip}}
  {\parbox{14.8em}{% mainmatter
    \hfill\huge\rmfamily\bfseries\thecontentspage}%
   \vspace*{-2.4\baselineskip}\leftbar\textsc{\normalsize{Story~}\thecontentslabel}\\\normalsize\rmfamily}
  {\parbox{14.5em}{% frontmatter
    \hfill\Large\rmfamily\bfseries\thecontentspage}%
   \vspace*{-1.95\baselineskip}\leftbar\normalsize\rmfamily}
  {\endleftbar}
% % %


\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother%

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{\hfill Contents \hfill}
\tableofcontents%
\thispagestyle{empty}

\frontmatter


\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{More Intro}

\part{The first part}

\mainmatter


\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\chapter{Third}
\chapter{Fourth}
\chapter{Fifth}


\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}
\part{Another part}

\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\chapter{Third}
\chapter{Fourth}
\chapter{Fifth}    

\end{document}
```

Why does `PART I` split over two lines? The setup is the same for the chapters, yet they don't split over two lines. Also, is it possible to get rid of the bar completely for `\part`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like some sort of incompatibility between `book` and `titletoc` (or rather, a strange design of `book`)...

What is written to the `.toc` for the `\part` is:

```
\contentsline {part}{I\hspace {1em}The first part}{v}
```

while for a chapter is:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}First}{1}
```

(notice the `\numberline`). Then if you add a `\show` before `\thecontentslabel` you'll see that it's empty, and the next thing your definition of `\titlecontents` does is a `\\`, thus the line is broken just after `Part~`.

This difference roots form the definitions of `\chapter` and `\part`. To fix this you have to inject the `\numberline` in the definition of `\part` so that `titletoc` can detect what is `\thecontentslabel`, otherwise it will think that the number belongs to the title of the section. Since you're already loading `etoolbox` you can do:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@part
  {\thepart}
  {\protect\numberline{\thepart}}
  {}{\FAIL}
\makeatother
```

and the output will be:

```
PART I
The first part
```

As for the left bar, I propose a rather bodge*y* solution, to avoid messing up the alignments: define a `Hiddenleftbar`, identical to the `leftbar`, but without the rule, and use this one for the `\part`. The `\part` entry will still be aligned with the rest of the entries, but will not have the vertical rule.

The output:

> [image]

Full code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[
    paperwidth=8in,
    paperheight=10in,
    inner=0.5in,
    outer=0.5in,
    bindingoffset=0.25in,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=1.25in,
    twoside,
    %showframe
    ]{geometry} 


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35835/121944, basis of this ToC design
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[compact,pagestyles,clearempty]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@part
  {\thepart}
  {\protect\numberline{\thepart}}
  {}{\FAIL}
\makeatother

% % %
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\rmfamily\contentsname}{}{}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}
  {\def\FrameCommand{\hspace{26.75em}%
    {\vrule width 2pt depth 3pt}\hspace{1em}}%
    \MakeFramed{\parshape 1 0cm \dimexpr\textwidth-6em\relax\FrameRestore}\vskip2pt%
  }
 {\endMakeFramed}

\newenvironment{Hiddenleftbar}
  {\def\FrameCommand{\hspace{26.75em}%
    \hspace{\dimexpr1em+2pt}}%
    \MakeFramed{\parshape 1 0cm \dimexpr\textwidth-6em\relax\FrameRestore}\vskip2pt%
  }
 {\endMakeFramed}

\titlecontents{part}
  [0em]{\vspace*{0.3\baselineskip}}
  {\parbox{14.8em}{% mainmatter
    \hfill\huge\rmfamily\bfseries}%
   \vspace*{-2.4\baselineskip}\Hiddenleftbar\MakeUppercase{\normalsize{Part~}\thecontentslabel}\\\normalsize\rmfamily}
  {\parbox{14.5em}{% frontmatter
    \hfill\Large\rmfamily\bfseries}%
   \vspace*{-1.95\baselineskip}\Hiddenleftbar\MakeUppercase{\normalsize{Part~}\thecontentslabel}\\\normalsize\rmfamily}
  {\endHiddenleftbar}
% % %

\titlecontents{chapter}
  [0em]{\vspace*{0.3\baselineskip}}
  {\parbox{14.8em}{% mainmatter
    \hfill\huge\rmfamily\bfseries\thecontentspage}%
   \vspace*{-2.4\baselineskip}\leftbar\textsc{\normalsize{Story~}\thecontentslabel}\\\normalsize\rmfamily}
  {\parbox{14.5em}{% frontmatter
    \hfill\Large\rmfamily\bfseries\thecontentspage}%
   \vspace*{-1.95\baselineskip}\leftbar\normalsize\rmfamily}
  {\endleftbar}
% % %


\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother%

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{\hfill Contents \hfill}
\tableofcontents%
\thispagestyle{empty}

\frontmatter


\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{More Intro}

\part{The first part}

\mainmatter


\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\chapter{Third}
\chapter{Fourth}
\chapter{Fifth}


\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}
\part{Another part}

\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\chapter{Third}
\chapter{Fourth}
\chapter{Fifth}

\end{document}
```