# Section titles alignement with titletoc

Tags: titletoc

with the following code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{chapter}
[0em]
{\vspace*{\baselineskip}}
{\mdseries \contentslabel[\thecontentspage] {0mm}  \hspace*{1.4em}  \chaptername 
\,\,\thecontentslabel \\
\hspace*{2em} \itshape    \vspace*{0.3\baselineskip}}
{\mdseries   \thecontentspage \hspace*{1.2em}   \itshape}
{}
[]

\titlecontents*{section}
[0em]
{}
{\footnotesize \thecontentslabel~}
{}
{\footnotesize,~\thecontentspage}
[~--\ ]
[]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Events and Probability}
\section{Composite Events}
\section{Composite Events}
\section{An Application of Composite Events}
\section{Probability}
\section{The Probability of an Unknown Constant}
\section{A Confirmation}

\setcounter{page}{277}

\chapter*{Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

how can I align the left left margin of sections titles with the chapter title?
I'm able to line up with an eye, but obviously it's a very bad idea...
thanx

**PS**

Now I realize another problem. The starred chapter is not aligned with the other titles. why?
[image]

**PS2**

i add an image of that I'd like to obtain

[image]

**PS 3**
With this complete code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\useosf
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage[margin=3cm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}

% book -- titletoc patch: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/454553/134574
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@part
  {\thepart}
  {\protect\numberline{\thepart}}
  {}{\FAIL}
\makeatother

\makeatletter

\titlecontents{part}
  [0em]
  {\addvspace{1.5pc}\filcenter}
  {\large\partname~\thecontentslabel\endgraf\bfseries}
  {\large}
  {} % without page number
  [\addvspace{.5pc}]

\titlecontents{chapter}
  [0em]
  {\vspace*{\baselineskip}}
  {\mdseries
   \llap{\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\thecontentspage}\quad}\chaptername~\thecontentslabel\\
   \vspace*{0.3\baselineskip}%
   \itshape
  }
  {\mdseries
   \llap{\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\thecontentspage}\quad}%
   \itshape
  }
  {}
  []

\titlecontents*{section}
  [0em]
  {}
  {\footnotesize \thecontentslabel~}
  {}
  {\footnotesize,~\thecontentspage}
  [~--~]
  []

\begin{document}


\renewcommand*\contentsname{\hfill\mdseries\huge Indice}
\tableofcontents

\part{Setting up of a Business}

\chapter{Events and Probability}
\section{Composite Events}
\section{Composite Events}
\section{An Application of Composite Events}
\section{Probability}
\section{The Probability of an Unknown Constant}
\section{A Confirmation}

\chapter*{Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion}

\clearpage

\chapter{Events and Probability}
\section{Composite Events}
\section{Composite Events}
\section{An Application of Composite Events}
\section{Probability}
\section{The Probability of an Unknown Constant}
\section{A Confirmation}

\setcounter{page}{277}

\chapter*{Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

the page margins and the index margins are different. Why? Index is narrower as page.... You can see it in the picture under
[image]

Comment: If I add a starred chapter to the ToC with `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion}` they look aligned... Can you please expand your MWE so that it shows the misalignment?

Comment: I updated code, recompiled. same problem, as in the figure above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had some spurious spaces in your `\titlecontents` definition, for example:

```
\hspace*{1.4em} \chaptername
```

produces a larger space than

```
\hspace*{1.4em}\chaptername
```

You also was using `\contentslabel` incorrectly. This macro reserves some space to the left of the margin for the label. But form your picture I assumed you didn't want it, so I removed and used a plain `\hbox` with `\llap`. I also added the `\part` formatting from [your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455421/134574):

> [image]

Updated code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titletoc}

% book -- titletoc patch: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/454553/134574
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@part
  {\thepart}
  {\protect\numberline{\thepart}}
  {}{\FAIL}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter

\contentsmargin[-1.55em]{1.55em}

\titlecontents{part}
  [0em]
  {\addvspace{1.5pc}\filcenter}
  {\large\partname~\thecontentslabel\endgraf\bfseries}
  {\large}
  {} % without page number
  [\addvspace{.5pc}]

\titlecontents{chapter}
  [0em]
  {\vspace*{\baselineskip}}
  {\mdseries
   \llap{\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\thecontentspage}\quad}\chaptername~\thecontentslabel\\
   \vspace*{0.3\baselineskip}%
   \itshape
  }
  {\mdseries
   \llap{\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\thecontentspage}\quad}%
   \itshape
  }
  {}
  []

\titlecontents*{section}
  [0em]
  {}
  {\footnotesize \thecontentslabel~}
  {}
  {\footnotesize,~\thecontentspage}
  [~--~]
  []

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Setting up of a Business}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\protect\draw[red,ultra thick] (0,0) -- (0,-7);}

\chapter{Events and Probability}
\section{Composite Events}
\section{Composite Events}
\section{An Application of Composite Events}
\section{Probability}
\section{The Probability of an Unknown Constant}
\section{A Confirmation}

\chapter*{Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion}

\clearpage

\chapter{Events and Probability}
\section{Composite Events}
\section{Composite Events}
\section{An Application of Composite Events}
\section{Probability}
\section{The Probability of an Unknown Constant}
\section{A Confirmation}

\setcounter{page}{277}

\chapter*{Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ok, thanx! I corrected my mistakes. your code solve the second problem, but sections titles are yet not aligned to left left margin of sections titles, as in my forst aid request

Comment: @user41063 Oops, I forgot that. Hold on

Comment: @user41063 Just to clarify: you want it exactly as in the picture you just uploaded?

Comment: centered part title (already solved), sections under chapter title, as in the picture

Comment: @user41063 I think it's correct now.

Comment: a last thing: after the part title (I'd like to have it without page number), in the following line, there ia an orfan page number

Comment: @user41063 Ooh, that page number is only because of the red line. I used `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\tikz...` to draw the red line in the correct position. Once you remove that line, the number will disappear.

Comment: perfect, thanx a lot!

Comment: a little problem more with margins. see the above code and picture plz

Comment: @user41063 Sorry the delay, I was in class. I edited the answer. Adding `\contentsmargin[-1.55em]{1.55em}` should solve the issue.

Comment: yes, now all perfectly working. but plz explain me... why 1.55em? where comes that lenght from?

Comment: @user41063 It's the default value of `\@pnumwith` defined in the `book` class. You can change it at your will, but make sure that it's large enough to fit the page number (`\@pnumwidth` is short for `p`age `num`ber `width`), and make sure that both values are equal, so that with your layout the margins are aligned.

Comment: ok. now all's perfectly working. thanx for your competence and kindness