# Handle part (book class) with titletoc/xelatex

Tags: titletoc

Referring to this thread: [Handle part (book class) with `titletoc`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455418/handle-part-book-class-with-titletoc)
, I've a new file, this time compiled with XeLaTeX (and no more with pdfLaTeX).

If I use the same code for `titletoc`, section titles are no more correctly aligned, I mean *centered*. It's very evident in the first part title, as you can see in the under picture:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\PolyglossiaSetup{italian}{indentfirst=false}
\frenchspacing

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@part
  {\thepart}
  {\protect\numberline{\thepart}}
  {}{\FAIL}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\contentsmargin[-1.55em]{1.55em}

\titlecontents{part}
  [0em]
  {\addvspace{1.5pc}\filcenter}
  {\large\partname~\thecontentslabel\endgraf\bfseries}
  {\large}
  {}
  [\addvspace{.5pc}]

\titlecontents{chapter}
  [4em]
  {\vspace*{\baselineskip}\mdseries}
  {\contentslabel[\hfill\thecontentslabel]{3em}\enspace}
  {\hspace*{0.5em}}
  {}
  []

\titlecontents{section}
  [4em]
  {\vspace*{.2\baselineskip}\mdseries\small}
  {\contentslabel[\hfill\thecontentslabel]{3em}\enspace}
  {}
  {\hfill\llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-1.3pc][l]{\makebox[1pc][r]{\thecontentspage}}}}
  []

\titlecontents*{subsection}
  [4.525em]
  {\footnotesize}
  {}
  {}
  {, \thecontentspage}
  [~--~]
  []
\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Title}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\chapter{Second Chapter}

\part{Long Title of the Second Part}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\chapter{Second Chapter}

\part{Very Long Title of the Third Part}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\chapter{Second Chapter}

\end{document}
```

What could be the cause of the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book code inserts a \hspace that you should remove too. Be aware that EB Garamond has not bold version and so the \bfseries has no effect.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\PolyglossiaSetup{italian}{indentfirst=false}
\frenchspacing

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@part
  {\thepart\hspace{1em}} %<----------
  {\protect\numberline{\thepart}}
  {}{\FAIL}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
%\contentsmargin[-1.55em]{1.55em}

\titlecontents{part}
  [0em]
  {\addvspace{1.5pc}\filcenter}
  {\large\partname~\thecontentslabel\endgraf\bfseries}
  {\large}
  {}
  [\addvspace{.5pc}]

\titlecontents{chapter}
  [4em]
  {\vspace*{\baselineskip}\mdseries}
  {\contentslabel[\hfill\thecontentslabel]{3em}\enspace}
  {\hspace*{0.5em}}
  {}
  []

\titlecontents{section}
  [4em]
  {\vspace*{.2\baselineskip}\mdseries\small}
  {\contentslabel[\hfill\thecontentslabel]{3em}\enspace}
  {}
  {\hfill\llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-1.3pc][l]{\makebox[1pc][r]{\thecontentspage}}}}
  []

\titlecontents*{subsection}
  [4.525em]
  {\footnotesize}
  {}
  {}
  {, \thecontentspage}
  [~--~]
  []
\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Title}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\chapter{Second Chapter}

\part{Long Title of the Second Part}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\chapter{Second Chapter}

\part{Very Long Title of the Third Part}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\chapter{Second Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx, now it looks perfect. PS This EB Garamond by Pardo has bold (and bold italic) version too: [link](https://github.com/octaviopardo/EBGaramond12/tree/master/fonts/otf); I use it in my real file

Comment: Both solutions work fine, I'm not able to say what's the best one. In any case, why  in standard classes \part is handeled in a non-standard way? 
is there anything that could (and should) be reviewed or corrected by programmers?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the non-standard way `\part` is handeled in standard classes, you have to load `titlesec` with option `newparttoc` and re-define the layout of `\part` with `\titleformat è . So I propose this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\PolyglossiaSetup{italian}{indentfirst=false}
\frenchspacing

%\makeatletter
%\patchcmd\@part
% {\thepart}
% {\protect\numberline{\thepart}}
% {}{\FAIL}
%\makeatother
%
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\bfseries\filcenter}{\partname~\thepart}{5ex}{\Huge}

\makeatletter
\contentsmargin[-1.55em]{1.55em}
 \titlecontents{part}
 [0em]
 {\addvspace{1.5pc}\filcenter\large}
 {\makebox[\linewidth]{\partname~\thecontentslabel}\endgraf\bfseries\makebox[\linewidth]}
 {\large}
 {}
 [\addvspace{.5pc}]
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [4em]
  {\vspace*{\baselineskip}\mdseries}
  {\contentslabel[\hfill\thecontentslabel]{3em}\enspace}
  {\hspace*{0.5em}}
  {}
  []

\titlecontents{section}
  [4em]
  {\vspace*{.2\baselineskip}\mdseries\small}
  {\contentslabel[\hfill\thecontentslabel]{3em}\enspace}
  {}
  {\hfill\llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-1.3pc][l]{\makebox[1pc][r]{\thecontentspage}}}}
  []

\titlecontents*{subsection}
  [4.525em]
  {\footnotesize}
  {}
  {}
  {, \thecontentspage}
  [~--~]
  []
\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Title}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\chapter{Second Chapter}

\part{Long Title of the Second Part}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\chapter{Second Chapter}

\part{Very Long Title of the Third Part}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\chapter{Second Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]