# Subsection titles (and not only) alignement with titletoc

Tags: titletoc

Referring to this tread [Section titles alignement with titletoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455346/section-titles-alignement-with-titletoc)
I've a further and (I hope) last question. I've a problem to apply this code to subsection to obtain this result:
[image]
My (wrong) code it's only a rough and wrong attempt to change the fine code already suggested to me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{EB Garamond}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%% TABLE OF CONTENTS SETTINGS
\usepackage{titletoc}

% book -- titletoc patch for \part:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/454553/134574
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@part
  {\thepart}
  {\protect\numberline{\thepart}}
  {}{\FAIL}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\contentsmargin[-1.55em]{1.55em}

\titlecontents{chapter}
  [0em]
  {\vspace*{\baselineskip}}
  {\mdseries
   \llap{\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil}\quad}\thecontentslabel
   \vspace*{0.1\baselineskip}%
   \upshape
  }
  {\mdseries
   \llap{\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\thecontentspage}\quad}
  }
  {}
  []

\titlecontents{section}
  [0em]
  {\vspace*{\baselineskip}}
  {\mdseries
   \llap{\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\thecontentspage}\quad}\thecontentslabel}
  {\mdseries
   \llap{\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\thecontentspage}\quad}
  }
  {}
  []

\titlecontents*{subsection}
  [0em]
  {}
  {\footnotesize}
  {}
  {\footnotesize,~\thecontentspage}
  [~--~]
  []

\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother
% make chapter begin from 1 every part

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\scshape\roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{\hfill\mdseries\huge Contents}
% put ToC title in the right side of the page

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A Very Short History of Rethorics}
\section{The Greek World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}

\chapter{A Very Short History of Rethorics}
\section{The Greek World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}

\end{document}
```

I was not able to product the correct alignement of chapter and section numbers.

At last, I don't understand why

```
\renewcommand*\contentsname{\hfill\mdseries\huge Contents}
```

works only if I put in after \begin{document}, and not into the preamble

thanx!

**ADDEDNDUM NOVEMBER 4TH**

I've a further, little problem with numberless chapters. Consider the following code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ bottero:1992,
  author       = "Vickers, Brian.",
  title        = "In Defence of Rhetorics",
  publisher    = "Clarendon Press",
  location     = "Oxford",
  year         = "1989",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{EB Garamond}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{chapter}
[3em]
{\vspace*{\baselineskip}\mdseries}
{\contentslabel[\hfill\thecontentslabel\phantom{.}]{3em}\enspace}
{}
{\hfill\llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-1.3pc][l]{\thecontentspage}}}
[]

\titlecontents{section}
  [3em]
  {\vspace*{\baselineskip}\mdseries}
  {\contentslabel[\hfill\thecontentslabel]{3em}\enspace}
  {}
{\hfill\llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-1.3pc][l]{\thecontentspage}}}
  []

\titlecontents*{subsection}
  [3.525em]
  {\footnotesize}
  {}
  {}
  {,~\thecontentspage}
  [~--~]
  []

\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother
% make chapter begin from 1 every part

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\scshape\roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=philosophy-verbose,scauthors=all,%
lowscauthors=true,giveninits,classical=true,volnumformat=strings,%
volumeformat=romansc,sorting=nyt,commacit=true,citepages=omit,%
editionformat=superscript,indexing]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{\hfill\mdseries\huge Contents\hspace*{1.2em}}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A Very Short History of Rhetoric}
\section{The Greek World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}

\chapter{A Very Short History of Rhetoric}
\section{The Greek World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

You'll realize that the chapter title *Bibliography* protrudes respect the other titles, as in the attached pic:

[image]

How is it possible to aligne it correctly? Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ bottero:1992,
  author = "Vickers, Brian.",
  title = "In Defence of Rhetorics",
  publisher = "Clarendon Press",
  location = "Oxford",
  year = "1989",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{EB Garamond}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{chapter}
[3em]
{\vspace*{\baselineskip}\mdseries}
{\contentslabel[\hfill\thecontentslabel\phantom{.}]{3em}\enspace}
{\hspace*{0.5em}}
{\hfill\llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-1.3pc][l]{\thecontentspage}}}
[]

\titlecontents{section}
  [3em]
  {\vspace*{\baselineskip}\mdseries}
  {\contentslabel[\hfill\thecontentslabel]{3em}\enspace}
  {}
{\hfill\llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-1.3pc][l]{\thecontentspage}}}
  []

\titlecontents*{subsection}
  [3.525em]
  {\footnotesize}
  {}
  {}
  {,~\thecontentspage}
  [~--~]
  []

\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother
% make chapter begin from 1 every part

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\scshape\roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=philosophy-verbose,scauthors=all,%
lowscauthors=true,giveninits,classical=true,volnumformat=strings,%
volumeformat=romansc,sorting=nyt,commacit=true,citepages=omit,%
editionformat=superscript,indexing]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{\hfill\mdseries\huge Contents\hspace*{1.2em}}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A Very Short History of Rhetoric}
\section{The Greek World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}

\chapter{A Very Short History of Rhetoric}
\section{The Greek World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}
\subsection{Aristoteles}
\subsection{The hellenistic Age}
\subsection{The Latin World}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it seems perfect! Some troubles in combining titlesec, titletoc and \marginpar, but I've to experiment more and better. In the meantine: thanx!!

Comment: all working fine now. Only, plz consider: I don't understand why
 `\renewcommand*\contentsname{\hfill\mdseries\huge Contents}`
works only if I put in after \begin{document}, and not into the preamble

Comment: You can write in the preamble `\AtBeginDocument{...}`. I suspect the problem comes from polyglossia, which redefines  `\contentsname`,depending on the language, and does so at the beginning of the document. Anyway, what you  did is bad practice: `contentsname` is not contents title formatting. You should define its formatting with `titlesec`, since you load its companion package `titletoc`.

Comment: Is the <command> I have to change with titlesec: `\contentsname` ?

Comment: No, you have to use ``titleformat{` with `numberless` key. It will reformat all unnumbered chapters, i.e. also the bibliography title, index title, &c.: they'll all be flushright.

Comment: So is it impossible, for instance, to have Contents title on the right and Bibliography title on the left?

Comment: And: `\titleformat{name=\?????` `Chapter?

Comment: You can, because you may use `\titleformat` after begin{document}. Or you may in `titleformat, but it would be more complex.

Comment: In the report class, yes, `tableofcontents` is a `\chapter*`.

Comment: open a new tread: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457623/titlesec-for-numberless-commands)

Comment: How did you calcolated, in ` \titlecontents*{subsection}  [3.525em]` the length of 3.525 em?

Comment: I did it by trial and error, checking with  a very big zoom.

Comment: thanx. however a similar _escamotage_ is not  suitable to solve my problem about biblliography title alignement...

Comment: Do you mean for the bibliography title which appears in the title of contents?

Comment: Yes, it protrudes on the left

Comment: I added code and image in **ADDENDUM NOVEMBER 4TH**

Comment: I tried with `\phantom`, but or doesn't work or doesn't compile

Comment: 've updated the code. The trick was to add the spacing between label and title (0.5em) in the 4th mandatory argument of `\titlecontents{chapter}`, which was left empty, and is used for the formatting of unnumbered chapters.

Comment: now it seems everywhere perfect. Thanx!