# Underline List of Algorithms, References, and Index with Victorian Ornament

Tags: overleaf, algorithm2e, underline, pgfornament

I would like to place a victorian ornament (`pgfornament` `80`) below `List of Algorithms`, `References`, and `Index`, all centered and capitalized.
Below is my minimal working example (MWE), but the ornament is frustratingly misplaced. Please help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex


\title{Question}
\author{Author}
\date{August 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle



\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF ALGORITHMS} 
%\centering  {\rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \vspace{-1.5cm}} 
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmcfname}{\hfill LIST OF ALGORITHMS \hfill}

\begin{center}
   \pgfornament[width=4cm]{80}
\end{center}

{%
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
 \renewcommand{\numberline}{\algorithmcfname~\oldnumberline}%
 \listofalgorithms 
}

\newpage
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1] \\


\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
initialization\;
\While{not at end of this document}{
read current\;
\eIf{understand}{
go to next section\;
current section becomes this one\;
}{
go back to the beginning of current section\;
}
}
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\section{BibTex}

This document is an example of BibTeX using in bibliography management. Three items 
are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \cite{latexcompanion}, the Einstein
journal paper \cite{einstein}, and the Donald Knuth's website \cite{knuthwebsite}. 
The \LaTeX\ related items are \cite{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite}. 

\index{Einstein}

\medskip

\renewcommand{\bibname}{ REFERENCES }
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{ref}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use the `titlesec` package to style your numberless `\chapter` headings; see e.g. [Titlesec for numberless commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457623/titlesec-for-numberless-commands)

So you might try something like this:

```
% Load the titlesec package
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Styling numberless chapter headings
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  {\Huge\bfseries}
  {}{0pt}
  {\filcenter\MakeUppercase}
  [{\filcenter\pgfornament[width=4cm]{80}}]

% But you'll need to provide for numberred headings too; so
% here I'm just using the default style
\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries}
  {\chaptername~\thechapter}{\baselineskip}
  {}
```

(In your code, the `\\` after `\lipsum[1]` should be removed)

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was hoping to do. However, when I try to do the same in my huge document, some chapter titles such as LIST OF ALGORITHMS and ACKNOWLEDGMENT disappear, but the ornament remains. It turns out my MWE was oversimplified. I'll make another MWE. If you have a hint kindly let me know.

Comment: The following worked for me in the cases that the above could not work: ```\chapter*{INDICES} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{INDICES}
\begin{center}
    \color{black} \pgfornament[width=4cm]{80}
\end{center}
\printindex```