# titlesec interferes with the part title in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, titletoc

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/582338/194994), I designed a simple TOC style. However, I find the TOC setting for part doesn't work normally if the title format for `\part` has been modified by `titlesec`.

Without `\titleformat{\part}`, the TOC looks like (which is the desired result):

[image]

However, with `\titleformat{\part}`, the TOC becomes:

[image]

How can I get the desired effect back?

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{book}

% \usepackage{titlesec}
% \titleclass{\part}{top} % make part like a chapter
% \titleformat{\part}[display]
%     {\filleft}
%     {\MakeUppercase{\partname}~\thepart}
%     {1em}
%     {\MakeUppercase}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@part% change the part style
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\numberline{\texorpdfstring{-~\thepart~-}{\thepart~}}\texorpdfstring{\\\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}}}
  {}{\FAIL}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{part}
    [0em]
    {\addvspace{1.5pc}\filcenter}
    {\thecontentslabel}
    {}
    {} % without page number
    [\addvspace{.5pc}]

\usepackage[hidelinks,linktoc=all]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily

\tableofcontents

\part{First part}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `newparttoc` option and to change the rendering of `\thecontentslabel`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}

\titleclass{\part}{top} % make part like a chapter
\titleformat{\part}[display]
    {\filleft}
    {\MakeUppercase{\partname}~\thepart}
    {1em}
    {\MakeUppercase}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{part}
    [0em]
    {\addvspace{1.5pc}\filcenter}
    {- \thecontentslabel\ - \\}
    {}
    {} % without page number
    [\addvspace{.5pc}]

\usepackage[hidelinks,linktoc=all]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily

\tableofcontents

\part{First part}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Suppose you want to process the contents in the toc. You can do something like

```
\titlecontents{part}
    [0em]
    {\addvspace{1.5pc}\filcenter}
    {\formattocpart} % numbered
    {} % unnumbered
    {} % filler
    [\addvspace{.5pc}]

\newcommand\formattocpart[1]{%
  \colorbox{red!60!green}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    - \thecontentslabel\ - \\
    #1
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}
```

The second and third mandatory arguments to `\titlecontents` are similar to the last mandatory argument to `\titleformat`.

[image]

Comment: With this method one seems to lose access to the title (`First part`). Can I somehow put it into a color box which, as I understand, only may be done by access to `#1`?

Comment: @Jinwen what precisely do you want to color?

Comment: Actually I want to put the title into a box to control its width.

Comment: @Jinwen In the toc or in the actual part title?

Comment: Just in the toc. To be precise, I wish to mimic the look of a typewriter, making sure all the characters are vertically aligned, thus sometimes the text needs to shift a half width of one character.

Comment: Perhaps this is too off-topic, I'll consider opening a new question on it. Anyway, thanks for your useful answer.

Comment: @Jinwen I added an example, see page 15 of the titlesec manual.