# Resources for designing a table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, examples, resources

What various packages, example code, or examples of existing documents with available source code are available to assist one in:

- Changing the style and formating of a table of contents?
- Building a new design for the table of contents from scratch?

Comment: [This post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31518/adding-a-per-chapter-image-along-with-group-of-entries-in-toc) and [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35825/pretty-table-of-contents) combined with a study of the `titletoc` package might get you started :)

Comment: The document of `tocloft` package is a good start to learn. Then `titletoc` package.

Comment: This is also interesting: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Table_of_Contents

Comment: @Ho1 Great tip for us beginners

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This post is community wiki, everybody is invited to edit.

### Packages

- [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft): provides many features for customizing the ToC and the and the ability to create new "Lists of ..."
- [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc): a companion for `titlesec`
- `tocbasic`: offers basic features for managing table of contents and similar lists, for package authors and class writers, is part of the [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle
- `tocstyle`: provides many ways of customizing the ToC and such lists, still in development, is part of the [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle
- [`minitoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc): for adding mini-tables-of-contents (minitocs) at the beginning of every chapter, part or section
- [`tocbibind`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind): can be used to add the ToC and/or bibliography 
  and/or the index etc. to the table of contents
- [`tocvsec2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocvsec2): gives control over section numbering and/or the entries in the table of contents on a section by section basis
- [`etoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc): (released a year after OP) claims a different approach than other toc packages. Instead of customizing an initial layout, you define  "line-styles" for each toc level toc and can inject code for transitions between levels.

The `memoir` class provides features which are very similar to the capabilities of `tocloft` and `tocbibind`.

### Style gallery

Click on an image to go to the source code and the explanation.

[image: Pretty Table of Contents]

[image: Adding a per-chapter image along with group of entries in ToC]

[image: List sections of chapter at beginning of that chapter]

[image: Changing color and bullets in Beamer's table of contents]

[image: Table of Contents with additional description of entries]

[image: All sections of a chapter in a single paragraph]

[image: TOC table with bullets between entries and page number]

[image: Table of contents with TikZ]

[image: Table of contents with TikZ]

[image: Table of contents with etoc]

Comment: Here you have another question with som examples [how-to-customize-the-table-of-contents-using-tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19796/how-to-customize-the-table-of-contents-using-tikz/19818#19818)

Comment: Nice answer. What about alternating dots like in the TeXbook toc?

Comment: @Stevan Kottwitz Very useful answer. It's helping me a lot.