# create list of thumbnails for each section

Tags: macros, programming

I want to create a cooking book. There I want to define for each receipe a thumbnail image.
At the beginning of each chapter I want to show instead of a TOC a gallery of thumbnails of each subsection (the title of each receipe is in the subsection).

I have same very basic background in LaTeX programming, but here I do not know how to start.

The sections are groups of recipes defined as

```
\newcommand{\recipesection}[1]{%
\phantomsection%
\stepcounter{section}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thesection\hspace{1em}#1}%
}
```

The recipes titles itself are printed as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\titel}{%
  \@startsection{subsection}%Name
{2}%Level
{0pt}%Einrückung%
{2\baselineskip}%beforeskip
{0.2\baselineskip}%afterskip
   {\font@recipetitle}*%
}%
```

I could define a command according to the section and subsection level which stored the path of the image.

However how do I save this to the aux file, so that I can read it afterwards and how do I know the number of section and subsections in a chapter so that I could define a galleray on that basis?

Comment: Possibly related/starting point: [Adding a per-chapter image along with group of entries in ToC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31518)

Comment: Not really. I am not convinced that a TOC is what I want. If so it would only be all items below a section or below a chapter. And I want a gallery, which means images in a tabular manner with 3 or 4 images per row. Therefore I assume that I need to program it from the start.

Comment: Ok, I think I have an idea of what you want. Could you put your snippets into a complete MWE so that folks have something concrete to start from. Perhaps you could add comments into your code to illustrate where you would like these galleries to appear

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech, have you considered creating an MWE for the community to work with?