# How to generate index page for report?

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing

I am writing one report in which i need to write page index in the beginning of report.

```
    XYZ 
    This is my first section which may use n number of pages.

    DEF
    This section may use m number of pages.

    ABC 
    This section may use p number of pages.
```

I need to add image also like shown below.

[image]

How can i control it and write it on index page.

Regards

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if you want the table of contents (simply adding `\tableofcontents{}`) or the alphabetic index, but this example make both:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}
\part{ABC}
\index{ABC}ABC 
\part{DEF}
\index{DEF}DEF 
\part{XYZ}
\index{XYZ}XYZ
\printindex{}
\end{document}
```

Remember that you need to run `pdflatex myfile.tex` twice to obtain atable of contents. If there are an alphabetic index, it is also needed a `makeindex myfile.idx` after  `pdflatex myfile.tex` to have a `myfile.ind` and then run `pdflatex myfile.tex` again.

Edit 1: As in the edited question you mention both `report` and `section` may be you will prefer change `report` by `article` in the document class and `\section` instead of `\part`.

Edit 2: The question ask now for include images in the table of contents. This is not trivial, but there a solution in [Resources for designing a table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38574/resources-for-designing-a-table-of-contents). Also could be of interest  [Include images in TOC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14956/include-images-in-toc).

Comment: I don't want to add it manually like page 10 or 29. Is there any way to do it automatically since i m using sweave.

Comment: Edited. Simply delete `\setcounter{page}{xx}` to have automatic page numbers.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. How to remove Part I/II/III and continue the text after title on same page.

Comment: @user15662 Please see the updated answer.

Comment: i edited my question.Pls help me.

Comment: Actually i need table of contents     XYZ   1   DEF  2 ABC 20

Comment: I need TOC XYZ 12 DEF 32 ABC 40