# How to put image in table of contents?

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents

My Question is similar to question which has not been answered. How can i put image in index page to improve look and feel.

[How to generate index page for report?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94946/how-to-generate-index-page-for-report)

[image]

Comment: I think you don't need this message but once again, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Also what do you have in mind when you mention *improve*?

Comment: Are you referring to *index* or *table of contents*? They are two very different concepts. If you're asking about the table of contents, as I believe, please state it clearly and at least add some information about what precisely you'd like to do.

Comment: I need something like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38574/resources-for-designing-a-table-of-contents?lq=1 but i  need image there

Answer (score 8):

Inserting raw content into the ToC is done using `\addtocontents{toc}{<stuff>}`. In order to survive writing such content, `\protect`ing is usually required. Here's a small example showing how to do it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newcommand{\addstufftotoc}[2][toc]{% \addimagetotoc[<toc>]{<stuff>}
  \addtocontents{#1}{#2}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image-a}\par}
\section{Second section}
\addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image-b}\par}
\section{Third section}
\section*{Fourth section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Fourth section}
\section{Last section}
\addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image-c}\par}
\end{document}
```

In the above example, `\addstufftotoc[<toc>]{<stuff>}` allows you to add `<stuff>` to the ToC of your choice (say List of Figures/Tables or Table of Contents which is the default). The example images are from the [`mwe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe). For unnumbered sections, `\section*` could be used, together with `\addtocontents` to insert the appropriate formatted title in the ToC (if needed).

---

Additional request: *Having the same size font `\section` in the ToC than in the main document body*

Sectional unit displays in the ToC is governed by the macro `\l@section`. The following is taken from its definition in [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls):

```
\newcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
```

The arguments passed to `\l@section` are the sectional unit number and title (as `#1`) and the page number (as `#2`). To match the font size from `\section`, we extract its definition from `article.cls`:

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

and redefine `\l@section` appropriately using a patch (for cleanliness; provided by the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{etoolbox,graphicx}
\newcommand{\addstufftotoc}[2][toc]{% \addimagetotoc[<toc>]{<stuff>}
  \addtocontents{#1}{#2}}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}% <cmd>
  {\begingroup}% <search>
  {\begingroup\normalfont\Large\bfseries}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image-a}\par}
\section{Second section}
\addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image-b}\par}
\section{Third section}
\section*{Fourth section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Fourth section}
\section{Last section}
\addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image-c}\par}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way to replace word Contents with Summary

Comment: @manish: Yes. Use `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Summary}`. For more details, see [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](http://goo.gl/CQdc6)

Comment: @Werner, Thanks, is thre any way to remove numbering 1,2,3 ...

Comment: @user15662: See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, but i observe one thing, Font size of section is bigger than font size of table of contents. Is there any way to control it?

Comment: @user15662: So you want the font size of `\section` in the ToC to be the same as the font size of `\section` in the main body of your document? Yes, they're different, but that can be changed.

Comment: How can we control it?

Comment: @user15662: See updated answer.

Comment: Is there any way to control the page number and position of toc? Actually i have 3 cover pages and after that table of content should be printed. How can i control it?

Comment: @user15662: It is possible to control this. However, you need to provide more detail and context. Consider [asking a new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) that contains all of this.

Comment: @Werner, I got the solution for it by putting \tableofcontents later wherever needed.

Comment: @Werner: I have one query, How can i move indented name without numbering to left aligned as show here http://postimage.org/image/6zu00vrhz/2b6189a1/

Comment: @user15662: How did you create those sections in the first place? What packages are you using the could format the ToC entries? All of these questions and uncertainties leads me to push you to [ask a new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) where you are able to provide a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that clearly reproduces your problem.

Comment: @Werner: i found its solution. Just for info i m using your code posted here. I need one more info is there any way to write a line in toc but without page number like \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Fourth section} but don't want to write page number here.

Comment: @user15662: To get rid of the space before an unnumbered (starred) `\section`, drop `\protect\numberline{}` from your `\addcontentsline` references. To avoid setting a page number, you could use `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Section Name}{}}`. Usually the last argument (empty here) contains `\thepage`.

Comment: Thanks! It works fine. One small question. Can i reduce the spacing between Section and line (\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Section Name}{}}).