# Add image to table of contents

Tags: graphics

I want to input different pictures to each chapter in table of contents like this image below, but I can't. Is this possible to use tikz to add pictures?[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put image in table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95020/how-to-put-image-in-table-of-contents)

Comment: I want the to put the picture in the left of the contents, not inline.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a marginnote as argument to `\addtocontents`, similar to the answer to the related question [How to put image in table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95020/how-to-put-image-in-table-of-contents).

The vertical position is more or less the position of the section in the TOC but you can adjust it a bit using `\vskip`.

To put images on the left you can use `\reversemarginpar` before the TOC and `\normalmarginpar` afterwards.

Note that you need a number of compilations (at least 3) for the image to appear in the correct position.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\normalmarginpar
\section{Functions and Limits}
\subsection{Four Ways to Represent a Function}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\marginnote{\vskip-9mm\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}}
\subsection{Mathematical Models: A Catalog of Essential Functions}
\subsection{New Functions from Old Functions}
\subsection{The Tangent and Velocity Problems}
\subsection{The Limit of a Function}
\subsection{Calculating Limits Using the Limit Laws}
\subsection{The Precise Definition of a Limit}
\subsection{Continuity}
\subsection*{Review}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{}Review}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much <3