# Customise table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm trying to customise my table of contents. I would like to set a colour for each of my sections, as you can see in the image below. Purple for activity, teal for lessons, and blue for exercices.

[image]

I'm just adding a counter to the definition of l@section to do that :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,french]{book}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{colorCounter}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{%
\refstepcounter{colorCounter}
\ifnum\c@tocdepth>\m@ne
\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
\vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
\setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
\begingroup
   \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
   \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
   \leavevmode \bfseries \large
   \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
   \hskip -\leftskip
      \IfStrEq{\thecolorCounter}{1}{
      \def\@linkcolor{purple!75}}{}
      \IfStrEq{\thecolorCounter}{2}{
      \def\@linkcolor{teal!75}}{}
      \IfStrEq{\thecolorCounter}{3}{
      \def\@linkcolor{blue!75}}{}
          \begin{tikzpicture}
             \node[fill=\@linkcolor,text=white] {};
          \end{tikzpicture}%}
     \color{\@linkcolor}#1
     \nobreak\
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
     \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
     mu$}\hfil\nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss
     \color{\@linkcolor}#2}\par
     \penalty\@highpenalty
     \ifnum\value{colorCounter}=3 \setcounter{colorCounter}{0}\fi
\endgroup
\medskip
\fi}   

\def\section{\secdef\@section\@ssection}

\def\@section[#1]#2{%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter{Probability}
\section{Activity}
bla
\section{Cours}
bla
\section{Exercices}
bla
\chapter{Tableur}
\section{Exercices}
bla
\end{document}
```

Except that, If I don't have an "Activity" section or a "lesson" section, it's not the good colour any more !

Comment: Can you please make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Of course. I'm sorry, I'm new to Latex and this website.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a new command `\lesson`  that sets the lesson title as well as the toc entry?  Avoids the akward if construction.

Comment: I tried to, but dots and page numbers are in black in the toc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Based on [Change images in custom ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306933/change-images-in-custom-toc)

This basically smuggles the colour changing instructions into the toc:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{%
\ifnum\c@tocdepth>\m@ne
\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
\vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
\setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
\begingroup
   \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
   \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
   \leavevmode \bfseries \large
   \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
   \hskip -\leftskip
     \sectoccolor\rule{1.7ex}{1.7ex}~#1
     \nobreak\
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
     \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
     mu$}\hfil\nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss
     \sectoccolor#2}\par
     \penalty\@highpenalty
\endgroup
\medskip
\fi}   

\def\section{\secdef\@section\@ssection}

\def\@section[#1]#2{%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}}

\makeatother

\newcommand*{\setsectoccolor}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\gdef\string\sectoccolor{\protect#1}}}  

\setsectoccolor{\color{black}} 

\newcommand{\Activity}{%
    \setsectoccolor{\color{purple!75}}%
    \section{Activity}%
    \setsectoccolor{\color{black}}%
}

\newcommand{\Course}{%
    \setsectoccolor{\color{teal!75}}%
    \section{Course}%
    \setsectoccolor{\color{black}}%
}

\newcommand{\Exercices}{%
    \setsectoccolor{\color{blue!75}}%
    \section{Exercices}%
    \setsectoccolor{\color{black}}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter{Probability}

\Activity
bla
\Course
bla
\Exercices
bla
\chapter{Tableur}
\Exercices
bla

\setsectoccolor{\color{orange!75}}%
\section{some other section}
\setsectoccolor{\color{black}}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

*(maybe it would be enough to smuggle the colour name into the toc, but as the above seems to work, I did not investigate further)*