# Compare \etocname with string

Tags: xstring, etoc

How can I compare the content of `\etocname` to a string? For example to choose the color based on the section name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoc}

\etocsetstyle{section}
    {}
    {}
    {\IfStrEq{bla}{\etocname}{\color{blue}\etocname}{\color{red}\etocname}}
    {}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{bla}
\section{blub}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a subtle point; can you please show a more realistic use case?

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your reply! I recently saw this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374319/customise-table-of-contents and wanted to do something similar and select the color based on three possible names of the sections. If I can test for the name, I can easily choose the colour.

Comment: You may try `\etocthelinkedname` instead of `\etocname`, but be careful that `\IfStrEq` doesn't work with several commands (say `\textbf` or accents) in its arguments.

Comment: @egreg Great! That works!

Comment: @egreg Sounds like your comment solved the problem. Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: @samcarter No, the example in the question does nothing sensible and some more is needed to test it.

Comment: @egreg `\etocthename` is perhaps better: `\etocthelinkedname` is a wrapper including hyperlinking hyperref stuff.

Comment: @jfbu Feel free to add an answer, if you can make a sense out of the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on a comment by @egreg, it is simpler to use `\etocthename`. It contains simply as a macro the section name as present in the `.toc` file. Of course you can have formatting macros therein. The `\etocname` is a robust macro which additionally contains hyperref stuff. The `\etocthename` expands in one step to the name from the `.toc` file (which may very well contain boxes, `\color`, `\textbf` or whatever..)

#### update:

The OP's code amended to use `\etocthename`. Also, I have added `\noindent` and `\par`, as this probably what will be used anyhow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoc}

\etocsetstyle{section}
    {}
    {\noindent}
    {\IfStrEq{bla}{\etocthename}{\color{blue}\etocname}{\color{red}\etocname}\par}
    {}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{bla}
\section{blub}
\end{document}
```

[image]

note: the `\tableofcontents` is always typeset by `etoc` inside a group, which limits the scope of the `\color` command, but in real application here you may want to add braces to limit more locally the use of the `\color` (for example if page numbers are incorporated to the TOC via `\etocpage`, to not contaminate them.)

note: testing `\etocthenumber` rather than `\etocthename` could be easier.